# Disable CSS rule using jQuery on a single page

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to disable this css rule on a single page:

```
[id^="ITEMROW_"]:hover
{
  background-color: #F6F6F6 !important;
}
```

Using the following jQuery:

```
$("id^=ITEMROW_").css("hover", "");
```

However, it is not working. The css code is still being applied.

Can someone help with this?

Comment: Possible duplicate — [Removing or altering CSS pseudo class in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6466586/removing-or-altering-css-pseudo-class-in-jquery#6466781)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change :hover CSS properties with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11371550/change-hover-css-properties-with-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because hover is a pseudo class not a property. You can't directly edit the pseudo class in jquery. Because it's not technically part of the DOM and therefore is inaccessible by any JavaScript. But you can add a new class with a new :hover specified.

Like

```
[class^="newclass"]:hover
{
  background-color: #F6F6F6 !important;
}
```

and toggle it

```
$('#ITEMROW_').toggleClass('newclass');
```

Comment: hope this will solve your query. if require more help just ask