# How do you add pseudo classes to elements using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, pseudo-class

In CSS, when you hover your mouse over an element, you can specify views for it using the :hover pseudo class:

```
.element_class_name:hover {
    /* stuff here */
}
```

How can you use jquery to add or "turn on" this pseudo class? Typically in jQuery if you want to add a class you would do:

```
$(this).addClass("class_name");
```

I have tried "hover" but this literally adds a class named "hover" to the element.

If anyone knows what to write, please let me know! Thanks!

Comment: You want to use jQuery to add a class to an element when the mouse hovers it?

Comment: This may help: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-triggering-css-pseudo-selectors-like-hover

Comment: Related question: [Manipulating CSS pseudo-elements using jQuery (e.g. :before and :after)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/manipulating-css-pseudo-elements-using-jquery-e-g-before-and-after/21709814#21709814)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can't force a certain pseudo-class to apply using jQuery. That's not how pseudo-classes (especially dynamic pseudo-classes) work, since they're designed to select based on information that cannot be expressed via the DOM ([spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#pseudo-classes)).

You have to specify another class to use, then add that class using jQuery instead. Something like this:

```
.element_class_name:hover, .element_class_name.jqhover {
    /* stuff here */
}

$(this).addClass("jqhover");
```

Alternatively you could hunt for the `.element_class_name:hover` rule and add that class using jQuery itself, without hardcoding it into your stylesheet. It's the same principle, though.

Answer (score 8):

I think there is no way to do that with jQuery or javascript.

You can find the same answer in these two questions:

1. [setting-css-pseudo-class-rules-from-javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311052/setting-css-pseudo-class-rules-from-javascript)
2. [css-pseudo-classes-with-jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/486159/css-pseudo-classes-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

Make a div on the page

```
<div id="Style">
  <style>
    .element_class_name:hover {
      /* stuff here */
    }
  </style>
</div>
```

And then programmatically hardcode the style, i.e.,

```
$("#Style").find("style").prepend("#" + this.id + ":hover, ");
```

Unfortunately, the element you are calling this will have to have an id.

```js
$("body").children().click(function(){
  $("#Style").find("style").prepend("#" + this.id + ":hover, ");
});
```

```css
/* demo */
* {
  transition: opacity 1s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="Style">
      <style>
        .element_class_name:hover {
          opacity: 0 !important;
        }
      </style>
    </div>

    <button id="btn1">Add hover class here</button>
    <button id="btn2">Add hover class here too</button>
    <p id="Note">
      To use this though, you'll have to assign an id to that particular element though.
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has a `hover()` function as seen here: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_hover.asp

It's a pretty nice function for `:hover` pollyfill.

`$(selector).hover(inFunction,outFunction)`