# Modifying :hover styling for an element with jQuery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dom, hover

I am building a WYSIWYG page styling editor with jquery/javascript. I'm trying to provide a way to modify the :hover state of links so my users can change the color, size, weight, etc of links. I know how to apply styling to elements for their default state, but can't find any documentation on how to apply styling to an element :hover state.

Any help out there?

To currently apply anything I am doing the following:

```
$('#content a').css('color','#ffcc00');
```

I need to do something similar for a:hover. ie:

```
$('#content a:hover').css('color','#000');
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you add pseudo classes to elements using jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12740967/how-do-you-add-pseudo-classes-to-elements-using-jquery)

Comment: How are you applying ANY style at the moment?

Comment: @putvande See my edit above. Just simple jquery css

Comment: Isn;t that already the answer? (The second line of code)

Comment: Maybe that will work with the event (on)hover for such. http://jsfiddle.net/pDuWN/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make the change using javascript you can attach it to jQuery.hover().
Here's a full working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/QDWGZ/2/)

```
$('a.link').hover(
       function(){

            $(this).css('color',$('input').val());
       }
     );
```

I built a WYSIWYG editor and I store the user defined settings in a db so instead of reloading the page after I save their change to the form I update the behavior with javascript.

Comment: If you haven't looked at TinyMCE you should. It's an amazing WYSIWYG editor you can use in your projects.

Comment: Just have a go at your answer to see if it does the job. I'm aware of TinyMCE, but this is a bit more complex of a project. The question is a simplified version of the actual project (WYSIWYG template builder). storing the styling in the db was the plan :)

Comment: Hm, it's pretty damn close. Hover doesn't switch off. I really don't want to go down the class route as I'll be dynamically creating the CSS.

Comment: This is the closest answer. Couple of changes I did: 'a.link' to 'a' and added a second function(){} for when a user mouses out.

Answer (score 1):

you can use css like assert your element´s id is

"element1"

css :

```
#element1:hover {
    background-color:pink;
}
```

Comment: @johnSmith Sorry, this is a CSS only approach. I've clarified the question.