# Javascript addClass with :after selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using `addClass` to validate my form. This is my javascript:-

```
if (name.val()=='') {
    name.addClass('highlight');
    return false;
} else name.removeClass('highlight');
```

and the css with the class I am adding is this :-

```
#coverup .highlight {
    border: 1px solid #a94442;
}
```

And this script above both works and is okay, however I want to add a glyphicon to the textfield as well as change the border colour, so that the error becomes more prominent to the user.

I then decided to simply change the code by doing another `addClass` method as shown below:-

```
if (name.val()=='') {
    name.addClass('highlight');
    name.addClass('highlight:after');
    return false;
} else name.removeClass('highlight'); name.removeClass('highlight:after');
```

and Then changed my CSS to this :-

```
#coverup .highlight {
    border: 1px solid #a94442;
}
#coverup .highlight:after {
    content:"\2715";
    color: red;
}
```

However doing this hasn't solved my issue, can anybody give me some options or guidance as to how I can simply add a glyphicon to the end of my text field if it isn't filled in as well as making the border change colour too.

Thanks!

Comment: when you use `:after`, css thinks it's a [pseudo class selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes) ... just use `.highlight_after` or `.highlightAfter`instead ...

Comment: `hightlight` is a typo.

Comment: @rafaelcastrocouto neither worked, thank you though any other help??

Comment: Why don't you use "append" to add an span with the glyphicon? Then, on every form submit event you remove all of them and check those fields again?

Comment: Update ( once you add highlight class, :after will be applied automatically ) - You cannot. Look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12740967/how-do-you-add-pseudo-classes-to-elements-using-jquery ALSO you have more than 1 statesment after `else` selection so enclosed them in brakets. Also look at the first answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/311052/setting-css-pseudo-class-rules-from-javascript for the solution.

Comment: Plus, you don't have to `addClass('hightlight:after')` .. You just have add the style rule for it in the css

Comment: typo sorted and made necessary changes, thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `<input />` elements cannot have child nodes.
- `::before` and `::after` psuedo-elements are treated as a child inserted before the first, and after the last "real" child respectively.

The above two facts considered, *you cannot apply `::before` or `::after` to `<input />` elements.*

Comment: So is there no way to add a glyphicon when no text is in a textfield via this method or any method for that matter??

Comment: You *could* use a `background-image`.

Comment: I used this previous however I couldn't figure out how to add the image to the far right with padding so its neat and also how to resize the background image?? any help there @Niet the Dark Absol

Comment: `background-position:right center; padding-right:24px; background-size: 16px;` Or something.