# Changing the hover behavior of an element

Tags: jquery

The big box here - http://jsfiddle.net/uwL3q7un/ - turns orange when you roll over it. If you click the small box it sets a flag that I want to somehow change the hover behavior of the big box to turn black when you roll over it.  I tried adding a class to `box:hover`, as you can see, but that doesn't seem to work.  Does anyone see a way to do this?

Thanks.

```
$(function(){
    var flag=false;
    $('#flag').click( function() {
        if(!flag) {
            $('#flag').css('background-color', 'red');
            $('#box:hover').addClass('hoverBlack');
            flag = true;
        }
        else {
            $('#flag').css('background-color', 'white');
            $('#box:hover').removeClass('hoverBlack');
            flag=false;
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: `$('#box:hover')` should be `$('#box')`

Comment: And `.hoverBlack` should be `#box.hoverBlack:hover` (in the CSS).

Comment: That's the result: http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/uwL3q7un/3/

Comment: And now observe the number of quick answers below that are similar to the comments above...

Comment: Yes, but you seemed to invite them by not putting your comment into an answer, which I would have gladly selected. BTW, do you happen to have the jQuery reference that explains why you're right and I'm wrong?

Comment: If the solution for the problem is small and easy (possibly maybe a duplicate), instead of downvoting and voting to close the question, I just leave a comment.

Comment: And it was really a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12740967/how-do-you-add-pseudo-classes-to-elements-using-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uwL3q7un/1/

You cannot add or remove a class on the `:hover` pseudo-element. You have to do it on the actual element and handle the hover state in the CSS.

JS:

```
$('#box').addClass('hoverBlack');
$('#box').removeClass('hoverBlack');
```

CSS:

```
#box.hoverBlack:hover {
    background-color:black;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this in your code 
http://jsfiddle.net/uwL3q7un/2/

```
$(function(){
    var flag=false;
    $('#flag').click( function() {
        if(!flag) {
            $('#flag').css('background-color', 'red');
            $('#box').addClass('hoverBlack');
            flag = true;
        }
        else {
            $('#flag').css('background-color', 'white');
            $('#box').removeClass('hoverBlack');
            flag=false;
        }
    })
});
```

And the css

```
#box.hoverBlack:hover {
    background-color:black;
}
```