# Programatically trigger browser's default hover effect on HTML input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Consider:

```
<input type="radio" id="a"/>
<label for="a">Hello</a>
```

When you mouse over the radio button or the label, the radio button gets highlighted. Different browsers highlight it differently, but it looks like a default behavior.
Now let's say there is a

```
<div id="bla">blabla</div>
```

somewhere else on the page.
Is there any way to trigger that default highlight of the radio button when mousing over the `div#bla`?

**EDIT:** To clarify, I was looking to "trigger" a native ":hover" pseudo-class of an element, which is not possible.
[Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#pseudo-classes)

Comment: add class to the input, on hovering the  div#bla

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**JUST FOR INFO**

to normalize your hover effect through different browsers:

```
input[type='radio']:hover{
//add your css here
}
```

you can also use :active, :checked, :before, :after to add more styles to it.

**ANSWER TO YOUR QUESTION**

Your question requires to handle the hover effect with some javascript.

```
$('#bla').hover(function(){
  $(":radio").css(//add your rules here);
});
```

**EDIT:**

My solution requires using CSS. What you want to get is to add a pseudo class (:hover) to an element. This is not possible. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12740967/how-do-you-add-pseudo-classes-to-elements-using-jquery) SO question for further details.

Comment: This requires writing CSS which would make it look the same in all browsers. I'm asking about triggering the hover effect without custom CSS. Like in FireFox, you would mouse over #bla and the radio button lights up in a blueish color (grey in Chrome).

Comment: the answer is in the second part of my answer. The first one is just an addition.

Comment: Lelio, I understand what you meant.  But .css( ) would require me to write CSS rules, which means that the highlight will look the same across all browsers.  I'm not looking to do that.  I'm looking to somehow trigger the default highlight behavior.  If you look at a radio button in FireFox, mouse over it, it would light up in blue.  Do the same in Chrome, it would light up in grey.

Comment: ok got it. So you only want to trigger the browser's event! Sorry, didn't get it before.

Answer (score 1):

From [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.9.1):

> More than one `label` may be associated with the same control by creating multiple references via the `for` attribute

Given that, you could just turn your `div` into another `label` to achieve exactly what you want without the need for any CSS or JavaScript.

Note that, if this new `label` is not a descendant of the `input` element's form then you should use its `form` attribute to specify the ID of the form

Of course, if you don't want focus to be transferred to the `input` element when clicking on the second `label` *then* you'd need a little bit of JavaScript but I wouldn't recommend doing that.

Comment: Great answer! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can't force the hover event via javascript, you have to simulate it. You can create a css class that creates the desired effects, you might want to use a border or something. Then you can toggle that class via javascript. Here's some code using jQuery.

```
$('#bla').hover(
    function() { $('#a').addClass('effect') }, 
    function() { $('#a').removeClass('effect') }
);
```

Comment: This requires writing CSS which would make it look the same in all browsers.  I'm asking about triggering the hover effect without custom CSS.  Like in FireFox, you would mouse over #bla and the radio button lights up in a blueish color (grey in Chrome).

Answer (score 0):

solution using native javascript. you can listen for click event on `#bla` element. and then set checked value of radio button on click and effects on mouseover and mouseout effect.

```js
var bla = document.getElementById('bla');
var aradio = document.getElementById('a');

bla.addEventListener('click', function() {
  aradio.checked = 'checked';
});

bla.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
  aradio.classList.add('green-effect');
});

bla.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
  aradio.classList.remove('green-effect');
});
```

```css
.green-effect{
  outline: 1px solid green; 
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" id="a" />
<label for="a">Hello</label>

<div id="bla" for="div#bla">blabla</div>
```

Comment: This requires writing CSS which would make it look the same in all browsers. I'm asking about triggering the hover effect without custom CSS. Like in FireFox, you would mouse over #bla and the radio button lights up in a blueish color (grey in Chrome).

Comment: @Dimskiy i don't think native radio button with label shows such glow effect on hover. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_label

Answer (score 0):

Check this out https://jsfiddle.net/L8aw5dts/1/

```
$("#bla").mouseenter(function(){
$("#lbl").addClass("hoverSimulate");
    $(".radioItem").prop("checked","true")
}).mouseleave(function(){
$("#lbl").removeClass("hoverSimulate");
      $(".radioItem").removeAttr("checked")
});
```

Comment: This code checks and highlights the label.  I'm asking about the radio button itself.

Comment: By "radio button itself" what do you  mean? Can you explain in detail?

Comment: I mean the <input type="radio"/>, not the <label> next to it.  Also, I'm asking about triggering the browser's default highlight.  Like blue in FireFox and grey in Chrome.  So, no custom CSS writing.  Thanks.

Comment: Got your point, but this cannot be achieved without writing custom CSS, if you do find a  way, do let me know