# Highlighting menu child after been clicked

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to change the colour of an child (In a menu) after been clicked by the user, and I'm having trouble to execute that.

I'm using class `.active` to change the menu style while scrolling down.
I was thinking about adding `.active::after` so each child of `<li>` tag that has been clicked will be changing his font color.

`.active` works fine, though `.active::after` doesn't work at all. Also the code includes scrolling slowly on click of child.

jQuery:

```
    /**
     * This part handles the highlighting functionality.
     * We use the scroll functionality again, some array creation and 
     * manipulation, class adding and class removing, and conditional testing
     */
    var aChildren = $("nav ul li").children(); // find the a children of the list items
    var aArray = []; // create the empty aArray
    for (var i=0; i < aChildren.length; i++) {    
        var aChild = aChildren[i];
        var ahref = $(aChild).attr('href');
        aArray.push(ahref);
    } // this for loop fills the aArray with attribute href values

    $(window).scroll(function(event){
        var windowPos = $(window).scrollTop(); // get the offset of the window from the top of page
        var windowHeight = $(window).height(); // get the height of the window
        var docHeight = $(document).height();
        var yOffset = window.pageYOffset;
        var breakpoint = 50;
        for (var i=0; i < aArray.length; i++) {
            var theID = aArray[i];
            var divPos = $(theID).offset().top; // get the offset of the div from the top of page
            var divHeight = $(theID).height(); // get the height of the div in question
            if (windowPos >= divPos && windowPos < (divPos + divHeight)) {
                if (yOffset > breakpoint){
                    $("nav ul").addClass('active');
                    $("nav ul li a").addClass('active');
                  }else{
                    $("nav ul").removeClass('active');
                    $("nav ul li a").removeClass('active');
                  }
                $("a[href='" + theID + "']").addClass("active::after");
            } else {
                if (yOffset > breakpoint){
                    $("nav ul").addClass('active');
                    $("nav ul li a").addClass('active');
                  }else{
                    $("nav ul").removeClass('active');
                    $("nav ul li a").removeClass('active');
                  }
                $("a[href='" + theID + "']").removeClass("active::after");
            }
        }

        if(windowPos + windowHeight == docHeight) {
            if (!$("nav li:last-child a").hasClass("nav-active")) {
                var navActiveCurrent = $(".nav-active").attr("href");
                $("a[href='" + navActiveCurrent + "']").removeClass("active::after");
            $("nav li:last-child a").addClass("active::after");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
nav ul.active{
  margin: -7px 0 0;
  background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
nav ul li a.active{
  color: white;
}
nav ul li a.active::after{
  color: #ccc;
}
```

How can I change specific menu child color on click properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using the css focus pseudo selector instead of after in my opinion.
As in

```
nav ul li a.active::focus{
  color: #ccc;
}
```

Please refer [here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/f/focus/) for more info.

Also, I don't think you can add/remove psuedo classes by using jquery as in $("a[href='" + theID + "']").addClass("active::after"); and $("a[href='" + theID + "']").removeClass("active::after");. For more details see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12740967/how-do-you-add-pseudo-classes-to-elements-using-jquery) and also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311052/setting-css-pseudo-class-rules-from-javascript) .You can probably add/remove some other custom class like `visited` etc. So that

```
 nav ul li a.active.visited{
  color: #ccc;
}
```

Comment: I was trying switching it to focus, yet didn't worked.