# Changing a CSS rule-set from Javascript

Tags: javascript, css

Is it possible to make changes to a CSS rule-set dynamically (i.e. some JS which would change a CSS rule-set when the user clicks a widget)

This particular CSS rule-set is applied to lots of elements (via a class selector) on the page and I want to modify it when the user clicks the widget, so that all the elements having the **class** change.

Comment: Looking at some of the answers, there seems to be some confusion about what your question means. This isn't helped by the fact that "a CSS class" doesn't exist, but two different things are commonly misdescribed that way. One is "An HTML class", but I think you refer to the other — a CSS rule-set (in this case, with a class selector).

Comment: I meant a CSS rule set for a class selector

Comment: related - [Setting CSS pseudo-class rules from JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/311052/104380)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can, but it's rather cumbersome. The best reference on how to do it is the following article: [Totally Pwn CSS with Javascript](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Totally_Pwn_CSS_with_Javascript) ([web archive link](https://web.archive.org/web/20130709232042/http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Totally_Pwn_CSS_with_Javascript)).

I managed to get it to work with Firefox and IE - <del>I couldn't in Chrome, though it appears that it supports the DOM methods.</del>[ricosrealm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/695639/ricosrealm) reports that it works in Chrome, too.

Comment: That's pretty cool! I had no idea you could do that stuff. Looks pretty advanced, though. And I can't really see a good use for it if you got a good framework like Prototype or jQuery, that will do most of that work for you...But still nice to know. Bookmarked for future reference (: +1

Comment: Here's a good use: http://stylebuilder.telerik.com/ :P And yes, it's advanced - using jQuery is probably much more suitable for the situation ;)

Comment: Here's some references from MDC:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.styleSheets
https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Stylesheet

Comment: Tested in Chrome 11.  Works great.

Comment: That guide is AWESOME!!! I've tested it on latest Firefox and Chrome and it works like a charm!!!

Comment: The link is broken (database down), but it looks like [someone turned it into a library](http://jelo.callee.info/docs/symbols/Jelo.CSS.html#.deleteRule).

Comment: This answer is outdated. See a modern solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38133146/2065702)

Comment: This answer is pretty much a link-only answer. and doesn't answer the question on-site.

Answer (score 14):

This is a modern version based on Totally Pwn CSS with Javascript. It's ES6 I hope don't mind.

```
function getCSSRule(ruleName) {
    ruleName = ruleName.toLowerCase();
    var result = null;
    var find = Array.prototype.find;

    find.call(document.styleSheets, styleSheet => {
        result = find.call(styleSheet.cssRules, cssRule => {
            return cssRule instanceof CSSStyleRule 
                && cssRule.selectorText.toLowerCase() == ruleName;
        });
        return result != null;
    });
    return result;
}
```

This function returns a CSSStyleRule that you can use like this:

```
var header = getCSSRule('#header');
header.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
```

Also **document.styleSheets** list references of the CSSStylesSheets Objects. Other way to acces a specific sytleSheet in the page is by assigning an **id** to the **style** or **link** element in the html code, and get it in javascript using **document.getElementById('my-style').sheet**. This are some useful methods:

*Major Browsers and IE9+ :* insertRule(), deleteRule(), removeProperty().

*Major Browsers, Firefox? and IE9+ :* setProperty().

```
<stye id="my-style" ...
....
var myStyle = document.getElementById('my-style').sheet
myStyle.insertRule('#header { background: red; }', 0);
```

It is also possible to dynamically create a new style element to store dynamic created styles, I think should be way to avoid conflicts.

Comment: This works great! I'd just add checking for existence of `styleSheet.cssRules` before calling find on it.

Answer (score 8):

You can edit CLASS in document styleshets as follows

```
[...document.styleSheets[0].cssRules].find(x=> x.selectorText=='.box')
     .style.background= 'red';
```

```js
function edit() {
  [...document.styleSheets[0].cssRules].find(x=> x.selectorText=='.box')
    .style.background= 'red';
}
```

```css
.box {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="edit()" >Click me</button>
<div class="box" >My box 1</div>
<div class="box" >My box 2</div>
<div class="box" >My box 3</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Depending on what you're trying to achieve, a better solution might be to change/add a class to a containing element (body would do!), and define classes accordingly.

```css
.yourclass { color: black }
#wrapper.foo .yourclass { color: red }
#wrapper.bar .yourclass { color: blue }
```

then you can just use

```js
document.getElementById('wrapper').className='foo';
```

(or your chosen js framework's wrapper for the same) to change everything with class `yourclass` inside whatever your `wrapper` element is.

Comment: In response to your parenthetical: yes, there's a way to specify code languages explicitly (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63800/interface-options-for-specifying-language-prettify)

Answer (score 4):

I tried the code via link from @alex-gyoshev comment, but it dosn't work

1. it fails on the CSS rules with Google fonts in Chrome
2. it fails on FireFox security checks

So I changed it slightly, but deleted `delete` functionality since it wasn't needed for me. Checked in IE 11, FireFox 32, Chrome 37 and Opera 26.

```js
function getCSSRule(ruleName) { // Return requested style object
  ruleName = ruleName.toLowerCase(); // Convert test string to lower case.
  var styleSheet;
  var i, ii;
  var cssRule = false; // Initialize cssRule. 
  var cssRules;
  if (document.styleSheets) { // If browser can play with stylesheets
    for (i = 0; i < document.styleSheets.length; i++) { // For each stylesheet
      styleSheet = document.styleSheets[i];
      if (!styleSheet.href) {
        if (styleSheet.cssRules) { // Browser uses cssRules?
          cssRules = styleSheet.cssRules; // Yes --Mozilla Style
        } else { // Browser usses rules?
          cssRules = styleSheet.rules; // Yes IE style. 
        } // End IE check.
        if (cssRules) {
          for (ii = 0; ii < cssRules.length; ii++) {
            cssRule = cssRules[ii];
            if (cssRule) { // If we found a rule...
              // console.log(cssRule);
              if (cssRule.selectorText) {
                console.log(cssRule.selectorText);
                if (cssRule.selectorText.toLowerCase() == ruleName) { //  match ruleName?
                  return cssRule; // return the style object.
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return false; // we found NOTHING!
}
```

Comment: the css rules  are case insensitives?

Comment: https://www.google.ru/search?q=CSS+case+sensitive -> http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#characters

"All CSS syntax is case-insensitive within the ASCII range (i.e., [a-z] and [A-Z] are equivalent), except for parts that are not under the control of CSS."

Answer (score 3):

The APIs for editing stylesheets with JS are, sadly, not consistent across browsers. The [YUI Stylesheet Utility](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/stylesheet/) attempts to smooth over these differences so you could just use that. You could also look at [the source code](http://github.com/yui/yui2/blob/c162da710816a67bd7738fdcfecdc88ae2174d47/src/stylesheet/js/stylesheet.js) to figure out how it works if you don't want to use YUI itself.

Comment: Is this still valid?

Comment: It says 'deprecated' and 'don't use this for new projects' right there on the site, so my best guess would be no.

Answer (score 3):

give your style tag an id, like `<style id="ssID">`
if someonelse is making your styles for you
tell THAT person to give the style tag an id -
that way you can access it directly without
scrambling around wondering what its index is

```
// create a hash table
var cssHash = {};

// loop through and populate the hash table
for (let i in (r = ss0.sheet.rules)) {

    // selectorText is the name of the rule - set the value equal to the rule
    cssHash[r[i].selectorText] = r[i];

}
```

now you have a hash table for everything in the style sheet -
note that some values will be *undefined*, but not for
any of the things you care about

if you have, for instance, a class called *#menuItem*
and you want to change its color to black, do this

```
cssHash['#menuItem'].style.color = #000;
```

that line will set the color of the style of the rule
whose index was looked up in the hash table (cssHash)
by the name '#menuItem'

more importantly, you probably have several different
classes that you want to change all at once
kind of like when you switched majors in college

let's say you have four different classes
and you want to set all of their background colors
to the same value, that some user selected from an input

the color selector tag is `<input id="bColor" type="color">`
and the class rules you want to change are called
*#menuItem .homeAddr span* and *#vacuum:hover*

```
// create a listener for that color selector
bColor.addEventListener('input', function (e) {

  // loop through a split list of the four class names
  '#menuItem .homeAddr span #vacuum:hover'.split(' ').forEach(function (obj) {

    // use the hash table to look up the index of each name
    // and set the background color equal to the color input's value
    cssHash[obj].style.backgroundColor = bColor.value;

  });

}, false); // false added here for the sake of non-brevity
```

Comment: Just passing through, but most of the time people here post the explanation above their code, rather than as comments mixed in with the code. You might want to consider doing that in the future.

Comment: This is quite a useful idea, but keep in mind that the ss0.sheet.rules can potentially have an element with key "length" and might even have "item" depending on browser etc.

Answer (score 2):

To check all stylesheets for the rule and set it:

Your rule:

```css
.aaa: {
  background-color: green
}
```

```js
[...document.styleSheets].flatMap(s=>[...s.cssRules])
  .find(i=>i.selectorText=='.aaa').style.backgroundColor = 'red';
```

Note that the css styles, when accessed through javascript, do not have dashes in them. In the example above, `background-color` becomes `backgroundColor`

Answer (score -1):

While `setAttribute` is nice, there is a standard way of doing this across most browsers:

```
htmlElement.className = 'someClass';
```

To do it over many elements, you will need a cross browser solution:

```
function getElementsByClassName( className, context, tagName ) {
  context = context || document;
  if ( typeof context.getElementsByClassName === 'function' )
    return context.getElementsByClassName( className );

  if ( typeof context.getElementsByTagName !== 'function' )
    return [];

  var elements = typeof tagName === 'string' ? context.getElementsByTagName( tagName ) :
    context.getElementsByTagName('*'),
  ret = [];
  for ( var i = 0, il = elements.length; i < il; i++ )
    if ( elements[ i ].className.match( className ) )
      ret.push( elements[ i ] );

  return ret;
}

var elements = getElementsByClassName('someClass');

for ( var i = 0, il = elements.length; i < il; i++ )
  elements[ i ].className = 'newClass';
```

You may want to replace the line:

```
if ( elements[ i ].className.match( className ) )
```

With some Regular Expression, but you will have to escape special characters in that case.

Comment: Regarding the last part of your answer, I think something other than match should be used, to account for multiple class names, in any order. For example, "foo bar".match("foo bar") will return "foo bar", but "foo bar".match("bar foo") will return null. Perhaps splitting by spaces and checking all class names in a for loop would work (however, leading/trailing white space should be ignored, and care taken not to get an empty string in array from an extra space somewhere). Reference: [W3 Semantics](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#dom-document-getelementsbyclassname)