# Dynamically generate CSS code using Javascript

Tags: javascript, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Changing a CSS rule-set from Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409225/changing-a-css-rule-set-from-javascript)

Dear experts,

Is there a way to dynamically generate a CSS stylesheets using Javascript according to what the users fill in on a form (user interface)?

If this isn't possible with Javascript, could someone point me to the right direction. Ruby on rails would also be fine.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you can. But you have to validate the user input. And write some kind of a css-processor to search the input text for the elements themselves and the according css-rules.

Finding css-rules is easy - they are all inside the braces {...} and the elements to which you apply the rules are outside the braces {...} .an .element {...}

You'll end up with something like this [css playground](http://cssdesk.com/)

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do that.. Lets say you have a input fields.. and whenever user changes value in the input field, then you want to add some special css..

```
 $('#form input').change(function(){
     $('#someElement').css({
              'background-color': 'green';
          });
 });
```

Comment: this probably only sets the element "style", but the preferred way would be to dynamically define a "class" which can be added like $('#someElement').addClass(newlyCreatedClassName)