# Is it possible to alter a CSS stylesheet using JavaScript? (NOT the style of an object, but the stylesheet itself)

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible to alter a CSS stylesheet using JavaScript?

I am **NOT** talking about:

```
document.getElementById('id').style._____='.....';
```

I **AM** talking about altering:

```
#id {
    param: value;
}
```

besides doing something dirty (which we haven’t tried yet btw), like creating a new object in the head, innerHTML a style tag in there, etc. Although this, even if it did work, would pose a few issues as the style block is already defined elsewhere, and I’m not sure when/if the browser would even parse a dynamically created style block?

Comment: It’s probably worth trying creating a `<style>` element in JavaScript, then appending it to the end of the `<head>` element. I suspect it would be applied immediately upon being appended, just like a `<link>`to a stylesheet would. Probably more reliable than attempting to edit the stylesheet itself.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Yes you can; every browser supports this, including IE9+).

- The [`insertRule()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/insertRule) method allows dynamic addition of rules to a stylesheet.
- With [`deleteRule()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/deleteRule), you can remove existing rules from a stylesheet.
- Rules within a stylesheet can be accessed via the [`cssRules`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet) attributes of a stylesheet.

Answer (score 16):

We can use a combination of [`.insertRule`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/insertRule) and [`.cssRules`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/insertRule) to be able to do this all the way back to IE9:

```
function changeStylesheetRule(stylesheet, selector, property, value) {
    // Make the strings lowercase
    selector = selector.toLowerCase();
    property = property.toLowerCase();
    value = value.toLowerCase();
    
    // Change it if it exists
    for(var i = 0; i < stylesheet.cssRules.length; i++) {
        var rule = stylesheet.cssRules[i];
        if(rule.selectorText === selector) {
            rule.style[property] = value;
            return;
        }
    }
  
    // Add it if it does not
    stylesheet.insertRule(selector + " { " + property + ": " + value + "; }", 0);
}

// Used like so:
changeStylesheetRule(s, "body", "color", "rebeccapurple");
```

#### [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/rg7c5yny/13/)

Comment: If you're having trouble with old browsers, changing `.cssRules` to `.rules` may help. You can also leave out the second parameter of `.insertRule` for Chrome, but other browsers like FF require it

Comment: If your browser does not update when modifying a style, you can instead delete the style before re-adding it. Do this by changing the `for` loop and adding `s.deleteRule(i)` and removing the `return` statement.

Comment: Also worth noting that due to the lowercasing, attributes such as `backgroundPosition` will not work. This will also need to be converted to its hyphenated equivalent (`background-position`) for use with `insertRule()`.

Comment: This doesn't work as OP intended. The edited rule is assigned to a <style> object as seen in the inspector, not the actual stylesheets.

Answer (score 6):

## 2020

Some advantages of this method:

- Does not require (but allows) stylesheet to be specified.
- Allows multiple styles to be added / modified at once
- Accepts `!important` attribute
- Ignores extra whitespace when matching CSS selector
- Changes last matching existing rule, or appends to end of last matching stylesheet. (Other answers add/change the first rule which may be then overruled.)

Usage:

```
adjustCSSRules('#myDiv', 'width: 300px !important');
```

Method:

```
function adjustCSSRules(selector, props, sheets){

    // get stylesheet(s)
    if (!sheets) sheets = [...document.styleSheets];
    else if (sheets.sup){    // sheets is a string
        let absoluteURL = new URL(sheets, document.baseURI).href;
        sheets = [...document.styleSheets].filter(i => i.href == absoluteURL);
        }
    else sheets = [sheets];  // sheets is a stylesheet

    // CSS (& HTML) reduce spaces in selector to one.
    selector = selector.replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
    const findRule = s => [...s.cssRules].reverse().find(i => i.selectorText == selector)
    let rule = sheets.map(findRule).filter(i=>i).pop()

    const propsArr = props.sup
        ? props.split(/\s*;\s*/).map(i => i.split(/\s*:\s*/)) // from string
        : Object.entries(props);                              // from Object

    if (rule) for (let [prop, val] of propsArr){
        // rule.style[prop] = val; is against the spec, and does not support !important.
        rule.style.setProperty(prop, ...val.split(/ *!(?=important)/));
        }
    else {
        sheet = sheets.pop();
        if (!props.sup) props = propsArr.reduce((str, [k, v]) => `${str}; ${k}: ${v}`, '');
        sheet.insertRule(`${selector} { ${props} }`, sheet.cssRules.length);
        }
    }
```

### [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/khrvndua/2/)

The method takes three arguments:

- selector [String] - CSS selector - eg: '#myDiv'
  Whitespaces are auto-reduced (`.myClass     #myDiv` will match `.myClass #myDiv`)
- rules [CSS String, Object] - eg (either is acceptable):

  - `{ border: "solid 3px green", color: "white" }`
  - `'border: solid 3px green; color: white'`
- sheet (Optional) [String, StyleSheet]

  - if empty, all stylesheets will be checked
  - 'myStyles.css' A relative or absolute URL to sheet
  - `document.styleSheets[1]` - A reference to a sheet

Other examples:

```
adjustCSSRules('#myDiv', {width: '30px'}); // all stylesheets
adjustCSSRules('#myDiv', 'width: 30px', 'style.css'); // style.css only  
adjustCSSRules('#myDiv  .myClass', 'width: 30px', document.styleSheets[0]); // only first stylesheet
```

Answer (score 4):

When I want to programmatically add a bunch of styles to an object, I find it easier to programmatically add a class to the object (such class has styles asscociated with it in your CSS).  You can control the precedence order in your CSS so the new styles from the new class can override things you had previously.  This is generally much easier than modifying a stylesheet directly and works perfectly cross-browser.

Comment: this is a great idea. we'll be testing various ways of doing things tonight and will get back with what worked best for us :)

Answer (score 2):

**change a property in a style rule**

```
function change_css_style (titulo,selector,propiedad,valor) {        
        let i=0;
        while (i<document.styleSheets.length) {
            if (document.styleSheets[i].title==titulo) {
                let y=0;
                while (y<document.styleSheets[i].cssRules.length) {
                    if (document.styleSheets[i].cssRules[y].selectorText==selector) {                                               
                        document.styleSheets[i].cssRules[y].style[propiedad] = valor;                                                                       
                        y = document.styleSheets[i].cssRules.length;
                    } 
                    y++;
                }               
                i=document.styleSheets.length;
            } 
            i++;
        }

    }
```

**DEMO**

```
<style title="chat_inicio">
    .contenido .mensajes {
          width: 100px;
          height: 300px;    
    }
</style>
```

change the style book with the title **chat_inicio** with the selector **.contenido .mensajes** the property of the style **width** to **475px**

```
<script>
     cambiar_css_style ('chat_inicio','.contenido .mensajes','width','475px');
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is:

Content CSS file:

```
#casesDndDropdown {
    background: #FFFFFF;
    border: 4px
}
```

You can override the **#casesDndDropdown** or any **CSS class** by defining it in the `<style>` tag inside body,

jQuery

```
$('<style>#id{background: #428bca;border: 0px}</style>').appendTo('body');
```

Answer (score 0):

.style.cssText property works, try the code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<style>
    *{
        margin: 0%;
        padding: 0%;
    }

    html {
        --theme-orange: orangered;
        --theme-blue: rgb(67, 67, 197);
        --theme-green: darkgreen;
        --theme-black: black;
        --theme-color: var(--theme-orange);
    }

    body {
        font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
        background-color: rgb(251, 251, 251);
    }

    .nav-bar ul {
        display: flex;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: var(--theme-color);
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        flex-direction: row;
        align-items: center;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .nav-bar ul a {
        text-decoration: none;
        margin: 15px 10px;
    }

    .nav-bar .theme {
        background-color: white;
        display: flex;
        height: fit-content;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: 20px;
        border-radius: 10px;
    }

    .nav-bar .theme .box {
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        cursor: pointer;  
    }

    .nav-bar .theme .orange {
        background-color: var(--theme-orange);
    }

    .nav-bar .theme .blue {
        background-color: var(--theme-blue);
    }

    .nav-bar .theme .green {
        background-color: var(--theme-green);
    }

    .nav-bar .theme .black {
        background-color: var(--theme-black);
    }

    .nav-bar ul li {
        color: white;
        font-weight: 500;
        list-style: none;
        padding: 10px 30px;
        background-color: var(--theme-color);
        transition: 0.2s;
    }

    .nav-bar ul li:hover {
        box-shadow: inset 10px 10px 10px -12px;
        scale: 0.95;
    }

</style>
<body>
    <div class="nav-bar">
        <ul>
            <a href=""><li>Home</li></a>
            <a href=""><li>Page 1</li></a>
            <a href=""><li>Page 2</li></a>
            <a href=""><li>About Us</li></a>
            <a href=""><li>Contact Us</li></a>
            <div class="theme">
                <a><div class="box orange" id="orange"></div></a>
                <a><div class="box blue" id="blue"></div></a>
                <a><div class="box green" id="green"></div></a>
                <a><div class="box black" id="black"></div></a>
            </div>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <script>
        function colorChange(color) {
            const htmlTag = document.getElementsByTagName("*")[0];
            htmlTag.style.cssText = `--theme-orange: orangered;
            --theme-blue: rgb(67, 67, 197);
            --theme-green: darkgreen;
            --theme-black: black;
            --theme-color: var(--theme-${color});`;
        }

        function addEventListenerForBox() {
            allBox = document.querySelectorAll('.box');
            allBox.forEach(box => {
                box.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
                    colorChange(event.target.id);
                });
            });
        }

        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', addEventListenerForBox);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Result:
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

#### 2023/2

A few years ago I read in [w3schools: HTML **style** Tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_style.asp) that the `<style>` element supports the [HTML Global Attributes](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_standardattributes.asp) and [HTML Event Attributes](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_eventattributes.asp).

The above means that, next to `href`, `rel` and `target`, **any** stylesheet can be disabled by toggling its `disabled` attribute. I had to dig deep to verify when and how this spec was implemented and found an old (**November 2000**) [W3C document](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Style/stylesheets.html) already mentioning support for the [`disabled` attribute of a stylesheet](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Style/stylesheets.html#StyleSheets-StyleSheet-disabled).

**tl;dr**

- putting `disabled` directly in the style definition like `<style disabled>` does not work.
- toggling the `disabled` attribute *false/true* with Javascript *disables/enables* the entire referenced `<style>...</style>` block, *wherever* this block resides in your document.
- Planning the position of style blocks in your document now becomes a matter of concern, as the regular browser logic is 'last in, first serve'.

All you need is a reference to a stylesheet element and a few Javascript oneliners:

```js
function disabledToggle(e) { e.disabled = !e.disabled }
function disabledOff   (e) { e.disabled = false }
function disabledOn    (e) { e.disabled = true }
```

**FYI**

- Check out the `media` attribute specification in the above W3C document.
- The `<link>` element also supports the mentioned *HTML Global Attributes* and *HTML Event Attributes*.

Essentially, it has always been possible to *kill a stylesheet with a single hipshot*.

A simple **proof of concept**:

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>

<!-- Alternate font, activated in default <style>, but can be toggled on/off -->
<link id="lnk-poppins" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Default styling, considered 'always active' -->
    <style>
        *    { box-sizing: border-box }
        body { font-family: Poppins, sans-serif }

        .square {
            margin: 5rem auto;
            width : 50vmin; aspect-ratio: 1;
            background-color: CornflowerBlue;
        }
    </style>

    <!-- Media controlled style, only active on small devices -->
    <style media="all and (max-width: 640px)">
        body { 
            margin: 0; padding: 1rem;
            width: 100%; min-height: 100vh;
            background-color: hsl(90,100%,50%,.3);
        }

    </style>

    <!-- Alternative styles: last in, first serve, so order matters -->
    <style id="stl-red"  >.square { background-color: Red   }</style>
    <style id="stl-green">.square { background-color: Green }</style>
    <style id="stl-blue" >.square { background-color: Blue  }</style>
    
    <!-- Default style, but can be toggled: overrides all above when enabled -->
    <style id="stl-default" >.square { background-color: Black }</style>
</head>

<body>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>&nbsp;Style Toggles&nbsp;</legend>
        <p>Colors:</p>
        <label for="default">
            <input id="default" class="radio" type="radio" name="group" checked
                   oninput="disabledOff(defa);">
            Default
        </label>
        <label for="red">
            <input id="red" class="radio" type="radio" name="group"
                   oninput="disabledOff(red);disabledOn(defa);disabledOn(blue);disabledOn(green);">
            Red
        </label>
        <label for="green">
            <input id="green" class="radio" type="radio" name="group"
                   oninput="disabledOff(green);disabledOn(defa);disabledOn(blue);">
            Green
        </label>
        <label for="blue">
            <input id="blue" class="radio" type="radio" name="group"
                   oninput="disabledOff(blue);disabledOn(defa);">
            Blue
        </label>
        <p>Font:</p>
        <label for="poppins">
            <input id="poppins" type="checkbox" oninput="disabledToggle(popp);" checked>
            Poppins
        </label>
        
        <br><br>
        <span>Old W3C Reference: <a target="_blank" href="https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Style/stylesheets.html#StyleSheets-StyleSheet-disabled">Attributes: <b>disabled</b> of type boolean</a></span>
    </fieldset>

    <div class="square"></div>
    
<script>
const red   = document.getElementById('stl-red');
const green = document.getElementById('stl-green');
const blue  = document.getElementById('stl-blue');
const defa  = document.getElementById('stl-default');
const popp  = document.getElementById('lnk-poppins');
    
function disabledToggle(e) { e.disabled = !e.disabled }
function disabledOff   (e) { e.disabled = false }
function disabledOn    (e) { e.disabled = true }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```