# Define global CSS classes using JavaScript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, styles

Is there a way to set the CSS of global classes using JavaScript or jQuery? That is, append `.my_class { foo:bar }` to the `<style/>` tag of the page?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to alter a CSS stylesheet using JavaScript? (NOT the style of an object, but the stylesheet itself)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620393/is-it-possible-to-alter-a-css-stylesheet-using-javascript-not-the-style-of-an)

Comment: Possible duplicate: [jQuery create CSS rule / class @ runtime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212500/jquery-create-css-rule-class-runtime)

Comment: Yes but put a **large warning** in your site's source, alerting anyone who works on the site in the future. In my experinece, sites with dynamically built/amended stylesheets are the most confusing things in the known universe.

Comment: Sorry, I knew this would most likely be a duplicate question but I've spent a few minutes searching it yesterday and could only find irrelevant links - mostly because the results were overshadowed by info about jQuery's .addClass.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Pure javascript -

```
var style=document.createElement('style');
style.type='text/css';
if(style.styleSheet){
    style.styleSheet.cssText='your css styles';
}else{
    style.appendChild(document.createTextNode('your css styles'));
}
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);
```

Comment: Well there are two right answers... chosing by Math.random().

Comment: While both answers provide a correct solution for the given question, I prefer to use pure javascript for performance reasons whenever I'm not trying to support old IE versions.

Comment: I'm adding the global CSS as soon as possible so that new elements are rendered respecting that new CSS. At this time, jQuery is not loaded yet and therefore pure JS is better option

Comment: Why there's that IF?

Comment: IF for browsers testing for the support of dynamic stylesheet, old IE in particular...

Answer (score 27):

Yes, you can do that in jQuery:

```
var styleTag = $('<style>.my_class { foo: bar; }</style>')
$('html > head').append(styleTag);
```

It works by simply appending `<style>` tag at the end of `<head>`.

Comment: Well there are two right answers... chosing by Math.random().

Comment: multiline styles: let styles = \`your styles here multiline\`; and then: var styletag = $(styles);

Answer (score 4):

This seems to be the way in 2023:

```js
const sheet = new CSSStyleSheet()
sheet.replaceSync('div {padding: 2px;}')
document.adoptedStyleSheets = [sheet]
```

Add more styles to existing sheet:

```js
let index = sheet.cssRules.length
sheet.insertRule('span {color: red;}', index)
```