# Using angular to change class settings

Tags: angularjs, ckeditor

There is a lot of information on how to use ng-class and ng-style on elements. But I was wondering if there is a way to use angular to change the "settings" of a class.

So for example, say that you had a css class that looked as follows:

```
.testclass {
    color: red;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

I want to use angular to change the color:red to color:black, without attaching angular to the HTML DOM object, but via the class instead.

OK, this isn't a very useful example. What I was really planning to use it for was to hide part of ck-editor (class cle_top) and I want to set the whole class to hidden when someone clicks a button (and visible if the click it again).

======== To make it clearer, this is the bit of HTML I want to hide =======

```
<span id="cke_1_top" class="cke_top cke_reset_all" role="presentation" style="height: auto; -webkit-user-select: none;"><span id="cke_8" class="cke_voice_label">
      Editor toolbars</span><span id="cke_1_toolbox" class="cke_toolbox" role="group" aria-labelledby="cke_8" onmousedown="return false;">
           <span id="cke_11" class="cke_toolbar" aria-labelledby="cke_11_label" role="toolbar"><span id="cke_11_label" class="cke_voice_label">
```

But I need to do it without being able to add angular hooks in the HTML code (like adding ng-class to the span, which would have been a simple solution)

Attached is a JSfiddle that shows my problem, and as you can see, the toolbar button does nothing.
http://jsfiddle.net/vrghost/uqvo3ceh/

Which kind of works now, it adds the class invisible to the span, however, it does not hide the span that it is looking at. 
Use the same process on a test text and it works...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone wanted to know how to do this, potentially this could be useful for other things as well.

Created a function that uses document.querySelector to find the element, then just do a toggle to turn on or of, and that, as they say, is it folks.

```
$scope.toolBarVisible = function(){
    console.log("Changing visibility");
    var element = document.querySelector( '.cke_top' );
    console.log("Just to do some debugging we check " + element);
    var myEl = angular.element( element );
    myEl.toggle();
    element = document.querySelector( '.cke_bottom' );
    myEl = angular.element( element );
    myEl.toggle();

    var myEl2 = angular.element( document.querySelector( '.test' ) );
    myEl2.toggleClass("invisible")

}
```

And for those that are looking closely, yes, it hides the bottom as well, and all without changing ckeditor or the code.
Hope someone finds it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply toggle the class off/on for that element when the user clicks the button? (Edit: You said you want to "set the whole class to hidden" - I am assuming you mean to remove the class?)

To answer your question though, you can do this with JavaScript using document.styleSheets.

See [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620393/is-it-possible-to-alter-a-css-stylesheet-using-javascript-not-the-style-of-an) and the [blog post](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/changess.html) it references. It mentions that there may be some browser compatibility issues. I have not investigated this.

EDIT: [This implementation](http://geniuscarrier.com/ng-toggle-in-angularjs/) of 'ng-toggle' will allow you to hide or show an element with a single button.

Comment: OK, should have been clear, I wanted to save my self some headache, so the ckeditor have a number of elements (both id and class), I doubt I can change them on load, and preferably I would like to avoid doing that, so thought I would shortcut by just picking up the class where that is for the whole toolbar (cke_top) then set it to display: none; and voila, I have hidden the toolbar for the user, if they want it back, press again, and there it is.

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand what you're saying, but maybe ng-style is what you are looking for? (See the live example at the following link)  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle You could use this to apply "display: none;" on click.

Comment: Added some comments on the question. My problem is that I can't connect angular straight to the object to add classes. So either if I can search the dom tree to "pick up" the object and hide it or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know of anything that will edit the class itself, but that probably isn't want you want to do. Other options are:

1) Create a second class, that comes after the first one in your CSS file that adds / changes the properties you want. Ex:

```
.testclass {
    color: red;
     background-color: blue;
 }
.newclass {
    color: green; // change property in first CSS class
    display: none; // or hide
}
```

Then apply the second class conditionally:

```
<div class="text-class" ng-class="{newclass: hideScopeFlag}">blah</div>
```

2) Simply use ng-if, ng-hide, or ng-show if all you are doing is hiding something. Ex:

```
<div class="text-class" ng-hide="hideScopeFlag">blah</div>
```

or

```
<div class="text-class" ng-show="!hideScopeFlag">blah</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution without messing with the stylesheets is to add a new rule like

```
.visibleOff .testclass {
    color: black;
}
```

and then you just need to toggle the "visibleOff" class on a parent element (the wrapper or the body element) of the editor.

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I am looking for, but how do I add that visbbleOff class by id or class.

Comment: If you're targetting only current browsers you can do it with plain javascript, 'document.querySelector("#elementId").classList.toggle("visibleOff");' otherwise use your js framework of choice.

Answer (score 0):

To hide certain elements in the DOM you can also use a $scope variable that acts as a boolean. You can set it to false by default and on button click toggle it to true and back.

```
$scope.hidden = false;
$scope.toggleHide = function(){
$scope.hidden = !$scope.hidden;

}
```

In your dom you can then wrap your element with an ng-hide="hidden" attribute like so:

```
<div ng-hide="hidden">...</div>
<button ng-click="toggleHide()">togglehide</button>
```

A plunker example can be found here: http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview