# how to permanently change/edit in css file by user input and save the chages in css files

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sass

In a form through text box user gives color code which has to be saved/changed in css file. when user again open the same page he has to get the last changed color

---

i am not talking about "document.styleSheets[1].cssRules" which changes stylesheet but after reshreshing changes will not affect. i want to save it in css file so that when user open the page again he has to get the last edited style sheet.

Comment: try this previous post
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620393/is-it-possible-to-alter-a-css-stylesheet-using-javascript-not-the-style-of-an

Comment: sorry u miss understood my requirement i want to change it and need to store it in css when user open the file again it has to show last changed  color

Comment: @Ninjakitteh the link what u people suggest is regarding changing **css file with respect to browser** only. It will not change the **server side css file**.