# Apply RegEx replace on all matched values in a CSS stylesheet

Tags: javascript, css, regex, replace

I want to be able to comb through a CSS stylesheet and select all matched values, then replace it using JavaScript. Let's say that I have 10+ values of "blue" in my stylesheet. Upon receiving user input, I want to change all the "blue" to "red" - I know there's the RegEx replace method but I'm not sure how to make it comb through a CSS stylesheet. Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have the stylesheet read into memory or it is a file?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6620400/6773269

Comment: Is "red" chosen from a fixed set of values? If so, why not create all stylesheets with the different colors and then only change the stylesheet itself.