# Net Core: Dynamic CSS with Tag Helpers not Inline

Tags: c#, html, css, .net, .net-core

Is there way to dynamically inject CSS into the CSS page and not inline html with TagHelpers?
 SetHtmlContent will create dynamic Html. Is there a similar Css method?  CSS and Html files should always be separate files I hear.l .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is. You can edit the CSS stylesheet using the `insertRule()` method in JavaScript. For more information, check out this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620393/is-it-possible-to-alter-a-css-stylesheet-using-javascript-not-the-style-of-an).

Comment: is there a way using c# net? not javascript