# Remove some classes from <style> tag in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, styles

I have a textarea wher there is some html like:

```
<style>
        a,
        body {
            color: #000
        }

        .test-row-1,
...
</style>
<div class="page-container">
...
</div>
```

In javascript I need to cycle on all elements inside "style" tag in order to do some stuff. 
Finally I need to create another "style" with only some of the classes inside the original one.
In the example I need to remove body class.

Is this possible?

thanks

Comment: There are APIs available in most (all?) browsers for manipulating stylesheets. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620393/is-it-possible-to-alter-a-css-stylesheet-using-javascript-not-the-style-of-a. This is a good article: https://davidwalsh.name/add-rules-stylesheets

Answer (score 0):

Sections inside a `style` tag can't be accessed like normal elements in javascript. However, you can access individual HTML elements and change their styles.

In your example, you said that you needed to 'remove the body class', so I assume that this means you no longer want the `body` to have the color `#000`.

To do something like that, you'll have to get your element in javascript first and store it in a variable. There are several ways to get the body, you could use either of these methods:

```
var body = document.querySelector("body");
```

```
var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
```

Now, you can change an elements' style properties using the format `element.style.property = value`. For example, to change the color to red, use this script:

```
body.style.color = 'red';
```

Here is a working code snippet:

```js
var body = document.querySelector("body");

body.style.color = 'red';
```

```css
body, a {
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<body>
  Here is some text.
  <a>Here is a link.</a>
</body>
```

Note that the link remains black, because it is still defined that way in the CSS.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your reply. I don't have any body tag inside my html. What I realy need is to remove body class from  "style" tag because it overrides some other styles in the final page (where I have body tag). What I described is what an html editor produces and what is stored in database, and finally is what is loaded inside page of our webapp. So the problem is not remove style from an element, but don't have that class defined in "style" tag. However, if it's not possible, I think the only way to do that is to use "replace"