# How to edit CSS hashtags using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a page where i'm using both CSS and Javascript to edit values like:

```
document.getElementById("Doc1").style.opacity = "value";
```

However in this scenario, i can't seem to make it work because i can't get to #Image1

> #Image1 =/= element.style

[HTML,CSS Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11l03.png)

What i'm trying to do is change animation-play-state using the id = "Image1".
Any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you edit the style of an element using the following:

```js
document.getElementById("Doc1").style.opacity = "value";
```

You are setting the [inline style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ElementCSSInlineStyle/style) of an element, **not** the styles applied by the `#Image` block.

If you'd like to edit the styles applied by the `#Image` block, there is [some browser support](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6620400/7933478) for it using functions like [`insertRule()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/insertRule) and [`deleteRule()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/deleteRule).

Instead of editing the styles applied by a stylesheet, I would add or remove classes from elements.

```html
<div id="my-div" class="is-running">test</div>

<style>
  .is-running { animation-play-state: running; }
  .is-paused { animation-play-state: paused; }
</style>

<script>
  document.getElementById('my-div').classList.remove("is-running");
  document.getElementById('my-div').classList.add("is-paused");
</script>
```

Comment: So i tried your method and it did something when i changed it based on my needs.
The code i added was  : 
<style>
  #Image1 { animation-play-state: running; }
</style>
and the JS Code is : document.getElementById('Image1').classList.add("#Image1");
It does the job, However it creates a new class rather than editing the existing one.

Comment: Right, `classList.add` will add a new class. Again, I suggest against trying to modify classes applied by a stylesheet, and to instead control which predefined classes are applied to elements by modifying the element's list of classes. Sorry if I'm having trouble explaining this.

Answer (score 0):

You can either remove the # from the string and use `getElementByID` or just use querySelector and pass the full ID.

```
id = id.replace("#","");

document.getElementById(id).style.opacity = "value";
```

**or**

```
document.querySelector("#Image1").style.opacity = "value";
```

If your issue is the `animation-play-state` part you can use this method:

```
document.getElementById(id).style["animation-play-state"] = "paused";
```