# removing a style by class

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I delete two items at once?
I need to delete them by class. But I don't understand how to `he -> display: flex` `me -> text-align: left;`

I tried the code below but it didn't work.

```js
 document.getElementsByClassName('he')[0].style.color = null;
```

```css
.he {
  color: rgb(0, 162, 255);
    display: flex;
}
.he .me {
  text-align: left;
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="he" id="test">
    <div class="me">
    <h1>hey</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? What is the expected result?

Comment: If you're trying to delete the styles attached to `he` you could just opt to delete the class name by doing `getElementByClassName('he')[0].classList.remove('he')`

Answer (score 0):

**Alternative A:**

Create another class with for example `.unsetColor { color: auto }` and then add the class.

```js
for (const el of document.getElementsByClassName('he'))
  el.classList.add('unsetColor')
```

---

**Alternative B:**

```js
for (const el of document.getElementsByClassName('he'))
  el.style.color = 'auto'
```

---

**Otherwise,** see this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6620400/529725
which is inline with how you coding it.