# jquery: how to change properties of whole css-class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Changing a CSS rule-set from Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409225/changing-a-css-rule-set-from-javascript)

I know that there are no variables in CSS, but if it is possible to change body of CSS-listing on the page with JQ - it may be work around of this. Also, I know aboud addClass/removeClass, and css('blabla','blabla') JQ-methods, and it is not what I need.

Comment: That isn't a class, CSS doesn't have classes (it has class selectors, but that isn't what you are talking about). You want to change a rule-set (possibly one with a class selector).

Comment: You could use it to append a new stylesheet to the dom, which could contain styles to overwrite the existing css. Although I can't imagine a good reason why you would need to do so?

Comment: @Quentin thanks for correction, yes, I am talking about rule-set.

Comment: @Jeemusu look:
var color='black';
change_many_things = function(){
var style = document.createElement('style');
style.**content**+="body:{background:"+color+"}";
style.**content**+="other_element:{other_color_of_something:"+color+"}"
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a body class and then use CSS to manipulate only the class of body and then style everything based on your body class.

```
<body class="my-skin">
   <p>Lorem<p>
</body>
```

And in your **CSS**:

```
.my-skin p{color: red}
.my-skin img{border:2px solid #333;margin:5px}

.second-skin p{color:blue}
```

jQuery:

```
$('body').addClass('my-skin');
//or
$('body').removeClass('my-skin').addClass('second-skin');
```