# modify a css rule object with javascript

Tags: javascript, css, oocss

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Changing a CSS rule-set from Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409225/changing-a-css-rule-set-from-javascript)

I was wondering if there is any possibility to modify Css stylesheet declarations without going for inline styling.

Here is a quick example :

```
<style>
    .box {color:green;}
    .box:hover {color:blue;}
</style>

<div class="box">TEXT</div>
```

That gives a blue written box that turns green written on hover.

If I give inline styling for the color, the hover behavior will be lost :

```
<div class="box" style="color:red;">TEXT</box>
```

That gives a red written box, no matter what.

So my question is, how can one access and modify the css declaration object rather than overwriting styles with inline ones.

Thanks,

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You could use the `cssRules` on the DOM stylesheet object corresponding to your original stylesheet to modify your rule.

```
var sheet = document.styleSheets[0];
var rules = sheet.cssRules || sheet.rules;

rules[0].style.color = 'red';
```

Note that IE uses `rules` instead of `cssRules`.

Here is a demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/8Mnsf/1/

Comment: Precisely what i was looking for. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: This is good. I'm wondering if I can target specific rule sets without referencing its index location.

Comment: @Musixauce3000 What *do* you want to target the rule sets by?

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin Well, maybe by the label. Like div, .wrapper or #output . For example: `document.stylesheet[0].cssRules[".mockButton"].style.color = '#FFF';`

Comment: @Musixauce3000 Well the `rules` variable in my snippet is a [`CSSRuleList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSRuleList), essentially an array of [`CSSRule`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSRule) objects. Assuming you're only looking for style declaration rules, you could filter `rules` to isolate only [`CSSStyleRule`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleRule) instances, then filter those to find the ones where the `selectorText` property matches some string (or regex).

Answer (score 7):

Just define your classes, and assign/remove classes to HTML elements with javascript.

Directly assigning style to an element, has highest priority, It will override all other CSS rules.

EDIT: you may want to use cssText property, see example here [cssText property](http://www.stoimen.com/2010/03/17/jquery-csstext-helps-you-improve-browser-reflows/)

Comment: For this I would need to know what the modify style would look like in advance. What if the base style is based on user input ? For your solution, i would need to create a new css class on the fly, which is just a different way to see the access stylesheet problem

Comment: I updated the answer a bit, check for cssText property

Comment: Thanks but still based on javascript/inline styling edit: fast misread csstext is part of the editing stylesheet solution

Comment: I am not sure, how you avoid JavaScript, but you should check @Asad's answer too, seems more elegant than mine.