# How can I get the css file text via javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

If I have a style tag on my page with css in it and I write the following javascript I will get the css text of all style tags.

```
//compatibility: all
$("style").each(function () {
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

I want to get the same text from all link element css files, like the following script.

```
//compatibility: IE Only
$("link").each(function(){
    alert(this.sheet.cssText);
});
```

Is there a cross modern browser friendly version of the above script?

Comment: `document.styleSheets`.

Comment: document.styleSheets.cssText is IE only also. is there another way of getting it via document.styleSheets?

Answer (score 1):

Another way to access a CSS rule without actually accessing the stylesheet is to create an element, apply a rule to it and then access its properties with jQuery. Something like this:

```
var NewElement = $('.SomeClass');
var TheHeight = NewElement.prop('height');
```

Not sure if this would help but it's an idea. What are you trying to do anyway?

**Edit:**

```
var sheet = document.styleSheets[0];
var rules = sheet.cssRules || sheet.rules;

rules[0].style.color = 'red';
```

This is from the answer **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13528512/modify-a-css-rule-object-with-javascript)** I added a **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tw8zw819/1/)** Note that you must select the correct stylesheet index.

Comment: no, this doesn't help. I want to look for a token in the css text and create a new dynamic style based on it. for example: I want to create a new style based on a dynamic color code token. div{color:#COLOR1CODE#}. this is the concept anyway.

Comment: I don't understand this: "I want to create a new style based on a dynamic color code token."

Comment: i want to replace this css div{color:#COLOR1CODE#} with this div{color:red}

Comment: ok, now I understand better. Take a look at this link http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Totally_Pwn_CSS_with_Javascript

Comment: thanks for this but this is an IE only (and maybe firefox). i'm looking for a cross browser solution.

Answer (score 0):

The only possible solution is to use AJAX:

```
$("link").each(function(){
    $.get(this.href, function(css){
        alert(css);
    });
});
```

Or you can use [`document.styleSheets`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.styleSheets)

You can iterate over the style sheets:

```
var styleSheets = document.styleSheets;
for(var i = 0; i < styleSheets.length; i++){
    alert(styleSheets[i].cssRules)
}
```

Comment: I don't think I can get external css file contents with the ajax method and iterating over the styleSheet to get the cssRules or cssText is IE only. I'm looking for a cross browser method.

Comment: @user3693957 Why shouldn't the ajax method work in IE?

Comment: you cannot make an ajax request to an external resource. i.e. it can't be from a different domain.