# How to change width and height of <h1> text dynamically?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to change `<h1>` and `<p>` text's width and height dynamically. I want to get parents height and width, then use percentage for changing child's. But all my attempts are failed.

Here is my css example code:

```
#main-holder #category1 {
    height: 80px;
    width: 15%;
    float: left;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    border: thin solid #999;
    margin-top: 5%;
    margin-right: 2%;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 6%;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: top;
}
#main-holder #category1 h1 {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #FFF;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 20%;
    text-decoration: none;

}
#main-holder #category1 h1 a {
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#main-holder #category1 h1 a:hover {
    color: #999;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#main-holder #category1 p {
    color: #CCC;
}
```

in html I am using like this:

```
 <div id="category1">
        <h1><a href="category1.html">MOVIES</a></h1>
        <p>FOR ALL AGES</p>
      </div>
```

I added width and height like below, but it didn't help:

```
#main-holder #category1 h1 {
        height: 50%;
        width: 50%;    
    }
```

Comment: You can't make text-size responsive without javascript unless you are happy to make it adapt to the browser width...would that do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code, you dont have `#mainholder`, but used all the css with that.so none of the styles applied. So I removed that from css and used `line-height as 100%` along with height. As the `parent div` have `height as 80px`, hope this is working fine and this is what you expected.

**[Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gr1u77c9/3/)**

Added  `font-size:2.9vw;` for `h1`

```
#category1 {
    height: 80px;
    width: 15%;
    float: left;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    border: thin solid #999;
    margin-top: 5%;
    margin-right: 2%;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 6%;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: top;
    background-color:#666;
}
 #category1 h1 {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #FFF;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size:2.9vw;

}
 #category1 h1 a {
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}
 #category1 h1 a:hover {
    color: #999;
    text-decoration: none;
}
 #category1 p {
    color: #CCC;
}
```

You can use viewport value instead of ems, pxs or pts.

> 1vw = 1% of viewport width
>
> 1vh = 1% of viewport height

**Update:**  **[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/gr1u77c9/6/)**

For `<p>` Height alignment problem, Use background and border for `<h1>` along with height and line-height like this:

CSS:

```
#category1 {
    height: 80px;
    width: 15%;
    float: left;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;   
    margin-top: 5%;
    margin-right: 2%;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 6%;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: top;


}
#category1 h1 {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #FFF;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 80px;
    height: auto;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size:2.9vw;
     background-color:#666;
     border: thin solid #999;
}
```

Comment: What I mean is, in your demo application there is a slider(left of box), when you shrink with slider. You will see that the BOX (category) going smaller, however width and height of text font size is not decreasing.

Comment: Was just posting an answer with vw/vh! @goGud if you want to read more about viewport sizing read this: https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/

Comment: @K.B.M can I define max height and width ?

Comment: yes you can, but may I know is there any specific purpose for that

Comment: For example, if user use full screen or really large resolution, then <p> tag going bottom of bordered box.

Answer (score 2):

Why dont you use vw for font-size ?

```
font-size: 5vw;
```

[Documentation](https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/)

Answer (score 0):

To change the text size you should use `font-size:72px;` or `font-size:3em;`.

Comment: I dont want to give fixed size. I want to give dynamic.

Comment: dynamic means, can you explain?

Answer (score 0):

One of the options it to use `CSSStyleSheet` JS object.

Check this tutorial: http://davidwalsh.name/add-rules-stylesheets

This answer provides another approach: [modify a css rule object with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13528512/modify-a-css-rule-object-with-javascript)

You can get stylesheet object and manually modify properties:

```
var sheet = document.styleSheets[0];
var rules = sheet.cssRules || sheet.rules;

rules[0].style.height = '80px';
```