# JS How to change css class color from javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

I would like to change color from div class. I searched the net for some info, but it's not working for me.

I have css style class in which I have property ***background-color***, and I want to change this property from JS file.

I want in class **gmBox** change **background-color:**, how I can do this, from JS file?

```css
.gmBox {
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: yellow;
  color: black;
  font-size: 23px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="gmBox" id="gmType">GM12</div>
```

Comment: Sounds like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: You can't change the css file from a js file, instead you can use another class or inline styles.

Comment: @VladimirBogomolov can i have some example?

Comment: `document.getElementById("gmType").style.backgroundColor="red";` or `document.querySelector(".gmBox").style.backgroundColor="red";` AFTER the element has loaded

Comment: @mplungjan the question is about changing not element style but CLASS style (so your minium-effort link not apply to this)

Comment: While OP might be satisfied with an Y answer to their X question, the question itself is _not_ a duplicate to the link it was closed with. Kamil Kiełczewski actually answered the question as asked, and it is interesting in its own right (though few-to-none should have need to do so).

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski Obviously it does apply since OP was happy with the answer below

Comment: use jQuery ,  *jQuery("#gmType").css('background-color': '#343333');*

Comment: @Vishwa why? - OP did not flag it jQuery

Comment: @Vishwa It's 2019. Don't recommend people to use JQuery.

Comment: that's why I **suggested**  using jQuey if possible.much easier

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen what would you use? vanilla JS?

Comment: @Vishwa In 99% of the cases, yes. And maybe lodash for data manipulation utilities. If really in need of DOM manipulation and not already using a framework, maybe [cash](https://github.com/kenwheeler/cash).

Comment: didn't know about cash,thanks, give it a try

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen this is my jquery: `let $ = s => document.querySelector(s);` :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing this (button added just to show the toggling effect):

```js
$("#toggle").on("click", function(){
  $(".gmBox").toggleClass("toggleBgColor");
})
```

```css
.gmBox {
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: yellow;
  color: black;
  font-size: 23px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.toggleBgColor {
   background-color: blue;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="gmBox" id="gmType">GM12</div>
<button id="toggle">Click me to toggle!!!</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

To change class you need to edit document styles

```
[...document.styleSheets[0].cssRules].find(x=> x.selectorText=='.gmBox')
    .style['background-color']='red';
```

```js
[...document.styleSheets[0].cssRules].find(x=> x.selectorText=='.gmBox').style['background-color']='red';
```

```css
.gmBox {
vertical-align: middle;
padding: 10px;
margin: 5px;
background-color: yellow;
color: black;
font-size: 23px;
border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="gmBox" id="gmType">GM12</div>
```

Comment: Dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13528512/modify-a-css-rule-object-with-javascript, which would benefit from your entry