# Add CSS property to a class by JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How do I add new CSS property to an existing class?

For example, if I got a class name `.test` and already have some styling/properties.

And I'd like to add a new property `color: blue;` to this class name by JavaScript.

How to do this?

```js
const elm  = document.querySelector('.test');
```

```css
.test {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">Testing...123</div>
```

Comment: Also see [modify a css rule object with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13528512/modify-a-css-rule-object-with-javascript); MDN [CSSStyleSheet.cssRules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/cssRules)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can search all css rules and find the one with selector of `.test`, then add any property to the rule.

```js
let target;

outer: for(let sheet of document.styleSheets) {
  for(let rule of sheet.rules) {
    if(rule.selectorText === '.test') {
      target = rule;
      break outer;
    }
  }
}

if(target) {
  target.style.color = 'blue';
}
```

```css
.test {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">Testing...123</div>
<div class="test">Testing...456</div>
```