# on/off for css selectors

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have, for example, this CSS rules:

```
<style>
table {background:red;}
div {background:green;}
</style>
```

and the following HTML, calling a JS function:

```
<table onclick="turnItsCSS(on/off)"><tr><td>123</td></tr></table>
```

Is it possible for `turnItsCSS()` to toggle CSS rules for tables?

All I figured is to parse `innerHTML` in `document head`, but it doesn't seem to be sufficient.

Comment: I would recommend using classes instead of elements in your CSS rules. Then switching is a simple matter of toggling classes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing a CSS rule-set from Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409225/changing-a-css-rule-set-from-javascript)

Comment: I don't think you can 'disable' css, other than removing/changing it. I could be wrong.

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi, yeah, Frederic, I know, but I need to do subject for any selector in <style>

Comment: Oh. Quentin is right, then.

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery you can use the [`.addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) or [`.removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) (or more simply, the [`.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) function)

So, say you have a table:

```
<a href="#" id="addClass">Add CSS</a>
<table id="the_table">
    <tr>
        <td>Hello, World</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And you have the following CSS:

```
.table_red {
    color: red;
}
```

In your jQuery, you could have:

```
$("#addClass").click(function() {
    $("#the_table").addClass(".table_red");

    // Check if the class is active, and remove it for a toggle.
    // or use the .toggleClass() function.
});
```

Comment: I need pure html/js, and I think JQ's .addClass etc - that thing parses document.head part =)

Comment: And, what's wrong with jQuery in this instance? Its trivial to solve your problem with it.

Comment: I need to do subject for any selector in <style> (and possible in linked css sheets)

Comment: I'm still not quite certain why you can't use jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

This is a nice way to switching between css files:

```
<button onclick="$('[rel=stylesheet]').attr('href','http://www.example.com/css/menu_red.css')">red</button>

<button onclick="$('[rel=stylesheet]').attr('href','http://www.example.com/css/menu_black.css')">black</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use jQuery or JavaScript to change dynamically your objects style 
in JavaScript you can get element by id or class name and set style

```
var obj = getElementById("idName");
obj.style.width = "300px";
```

or

```
var obj = getElementsByClassName("classname")[0]; //return array with with all elements with same class
obj.style.width = "300px";
```

Comment: Thanx, but I need to disable selectors without altering element's property.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using HTML5, unfortunately i don't think it's supported in < IE10.

HTML

```
<table onclick="this.classList.toggle('on');"><tr><td>123</td></tr></table>
```

CSS

```
.on { 
    background-color:red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sGKgV/

**Check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/196038/1156119 for a thorough rundown of other techniques.**