# Make table cells responsive and make them evenly square, filling the window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make table cells responsive - even squares filling all available space(window).
If table width is 100% - it takes all available space, distributing cells evenly but only horizontally. I have written small javascript with jquery, calling this function on window resize event:

```
function windowReszie(){
 $("td").each(function(){
    $(this).css({"height":$(this).width()});
  })
}
```

But this approach is slow, because I have a lot of cells - is there a way to do it just with css or any other better , faster way?
[image]

Comment: did you try with `<div>` instead of table cells ? it could be much faster than with table.

Comment: Wouldn't I need to use javascript to adjust the width and height of the `<div>` anyway? I must have 7  responsive boxes horizontally and 14 vertically

Comment: yes, but `<div></div>` is rendered faster than `<table><tr>...<td></td>...</tr></table>`. but, this is not very big grid.

Comment: naah its just an example my grid is big 7 columns and 20 rows, but I'll give it a try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see some problem with your approach, you're computing the width for every cell.

I'd do something along the lines of

```
function windowReszie(){
  var size =$("td").width();
  $("td").height(size);
}
```

Another approach would be to set a class and change the css rule associated with the class, but that could be a bit tricky (see : [Changing a CSS rule-set from Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409225/changing-a-css-rule-set-from-javascript))

Comment: Cool, it worked perfectly, for some reason I thought that jquery would only apply this to first found `td` not all of them

Comment: Well the tricky thing is that for css property (e.g. `.css`, `.width` and `.height`) the function used to read reads only the first element whereas the set sets if for every element.

Answer (score 1):

try adding class only at first `<td>` in `<tr>` and then loop over that class... no need to check every `<td>` item.

Comment: Yours works too - thanks, but @Py gave a code example as welll - If I could I would accept both of your answers.