# jquery change default css for entire document

Tags: jquery, css

```
<style>
.foo {
   color: red; <-- how to change this from jquery
}
</style>
```

How can I change default css from jquery without $() selector? so entire  elements contain class will changed?

Comment: $(".foo").css("color", "red"); This doesn't work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing a CSS rule-set from Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409225/changing-a-css-rule-set-from-javascript)

Comment: You wan't to change foo class style from JQuery ?

Comment: cant change css inside of style tag?

Comment: @McCuz That's exactly what the OP doesn't want to do

Comment: Brainfart, you're right.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't override the value in your own stylesheet? Using JS for this isn't ideal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use javascript :

```
<head>
    <link id="style" rel=stylesheet href="large.css">

</head>

function changeStyle(){
        if(window.innerWidth<900){
            document.getElementById("style").setAttribute("href","small.css");

       }else if((window.innerWidth)>900 &&(window.innerWidth)<1200){
         document.getElementById("style").setAttribute("href","medium.css");   
       }
        else 
              document.getElementById("style").setAttribute("href","large.css"); 
    }  
    window.onresize=changeStyle;
   changeStyle();
```