# update CSS class on button click - Reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm trying to obtain a blur effect to my background when a user clicks a certain button. How can i update my css class when a user clicks the button.

This is the current css class i have

```
.post_options {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    background-color: #eceff1;
    position: fixed;
}
```

I want to make it like this make a user clicks the button

```
.post_options {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    background-color: #eceff1;
    position: fixed;
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
    -moz-filter: blur(5px);
    -o-filter: blur(5px);
    -ms-filter: blur(5px);
    filter: blur(5px);
}
```

This is the button that should make my background blur

```
 <button className="preview_btn" href="#postpreview" onClick={this.preview}>Preview</button>
```

> **Note**: I'm doing this in react.

I tried giving a separate div with the background effects but what it does is blurring the contents inside too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's keep this short and sweet. Assuming that if you are using JSX and consequently Babel then you can use ES6 arrow functions. Live codepen example can be found [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jBWYJV?editors=0010).

#### CSS

```
.blur {
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
    -moz-filter: blur(5px);
    -o-filter: blur(5px);
    -ms-filter: blur(5px);
    filter: blur(5px);
}
```

#### JavaScript

```
class Section extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
       blur: false
    };
  };

  render() {
    return (
       <section>
        <ul className={this.state.blur ? 'blur' : ''}>
          <li className="post_options">Option 1</li>
          <li className="post_options">Option 2</li>
        </ul>

        <button onClick={this.blur}>Blur</button>
      </section>
    );
  }

  blur = () => {
    this.setState({blur: !this.state.blur})
  };
}

React.render(<Section />, document.body);
```

Answer (score 5):

Set state in your class:

```
 this.state = {
    blur: false; 
  }
```

Create a function to be called when button is clicked.
This function changes the state and triggers a re-render

```
 preview() {
    this.setState = {
      blur:true;
    }
}
```

Check the state of 'blur' in your button component and add classes accordingly

```
//Below code adds 'blur' class if the button is clicked
<button className={this.state.blur?'blur':''} onClick={this.preview}>Preview</button>
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YZyZzJ)

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to change CSS rules from javascript, but I guarantee this is not the route you would like to take. See [Changing a CSS rule-set from Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409225/changing-a-css-rule-set-from-javascript)

Instead I'd just use the following two css classes:

```
.post_options {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    background-color: #eceff1;
    position: fixed;
}

.filter_blur {
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
    -moz-filter: blur(5px);
    -o-filter: blur(5px);
    -ms-filter: blur(5px);
    filter: blur(5px);
}
```

Then, you need your button to, on click, update the state to indicate that your `post_options` should render with the `filter_blur` class. How to do this will depend a lot on how your app is set up. For example, this will probably look much different if you are making a flux or redux app vs an app made of simple lifecycle components.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just make another class and toggle between classes?

All you need to do is move the modified effects into another class, lets say `post_options_clicked` and when the button is clicked in that method toggle a component state.

Lets say you have a simple component like this

```
const ExampleComponent = React.createClass({
    getInitialState() {
        return({
            toggled: false
        });
    },

    toggleState() {
        if(this.state.toggled){
            this.setState({ toggled:false });
        }else{
            this.setState({ toggled:true });
        }
    },

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
               {
                this.state.toggled
                ?
                <div className="post-options-clicked">
                  //Your Code goes here
                </div>
                :
                <div className="post-options">
                  //Your Code goes here
                </div>
               }
               <button 
                 className="preview_btn" 
                 href="#postpreview" 
                 onClick={this.toggleState}
               >
               Preview
               </button>
            </div>
        )
    },
)}
```

Answer (score 0):

**style**

The style attribute accepts a JavaScript object with camelCased properties rather than a CSS string. This is consistent with the DOM style JavaScript property, is more efficient, and prevents XSS security holes. For example:

```
const divStyle = {
  color: 'blue',
  backgroundImage: 'url(' + imgUrl + ')',
};


function HelloWorldComponent() {
  return <div style={divStyle}>Hello World!</div>;
}
```

See more at [DOM Elements - React](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/dom-elements.html)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend doing as Thomas says or you could call this function onclick()

```
function post_options_click(){
 var x = document.getElementsByClassName("post-options");
 x[0].style.filter= "blur(5px)";
 x[0].style.-webkit-filter= "blur(5px)";
 x[0].style.-moz-filter= "blur(5px)";
 x[0].style.-o-filter= "blur(5px)";
 x[0].style.-ms-filter= "blur(5px)";
}
```