# Styling elements after creating them

Tags: javascript

My current code creates a grid with span elements that have a class name of gridsquare. I'm trying to figure out how to apply styling to all of them. I keep getting the error TypeError: size.style is undefined. I have the function set to run after the elements are created, not sure what's going on...

```
let n=16;
let boxSize = 720/n;

function grid(){
  for(var i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    document.getElementById('container').innerHTML+='<div class="row">'

    for(k = 0; k < n; k++) {
       document.getElementById('container').innerHTML+='<span class="gridsquare">as</span>'; 
    } 
  }
  gridSize() 
}

function gridSize(){
  let size = document.getElementsByClassName("gridsquare")
    size.style.height = boxSize;
    size.style.width = boxSize; 
}
grid()
```

Comment: [*getElementsByClassName*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns an [*HTMLCollection*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection), you need to get the items one at a time (e.g. `Array.from(size).forEach(...)`). You can't set a style property value on multiple elements in one go unless they all have the same class and you modify the class rules, see [*Changing a CSS rule-set from Javascript*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409225/changing-a-css-rule-set-from-javascript).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use index while using `getElementsByClassName` because `getElementsByClassName` returns node collections.

```
size[0].style.width = boxSize;
size[0].style.width = boxSize;
```

**Working snippet:** By using `querySelectorAll()`

```js
let n=16;
let boxSize = 720/n;

function grid(){
  for(var i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    document.getElementById('container').innerHTML+='<div class="row">'

    for(k = 0; k < n; k++) {
       document.getElementById('container').innerHTML+='<span class="gridsquare">as</span>'; 
    } 
  }
  gridSize(); 
}

function gridSize(){
  let boxSize = '20px';
  let size = document.querySelectorAll(".gridsquare");
  size.forEach(function(spanEl){
      spanEl.style.height = boxSize;
      spanEl.style.width = boxSize;
      spanEl.style.display = 'inline-block';
  });
}
grid();
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

**OR:** If you want to use `getElementsByClassName()`

```js
let n=16;
let boxSize = 720/n;

function grid(){
  for(var i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    document.getElementById('container').innerHTML+='<div class="row">'

    for(k = 0; k < n; k++) {
       document.getElementById('container').innerHTML+='<span class="gridsquare">as</span>'; 
    } 
  }
  gridSize(); 
}

function gridSize(){
  let boxSize = '20px';
  let size = document.getElementsByClassName("gridsquare");
  [].forEach.call(size, function(spanEl){
      spanEl.style.height = boxSize;
      spanEl.style.width = boxSize;
      spanEl.style.display = 'inline-block';
  });
}
grid();
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: [0] index only selects the first element. I tried the .every method but gave me my original error. I'm trying to select all of them.

Comment: @JacobMoore, I have updated my answer...please check.

Comment: @JacobMoore, plaese note I have used `querySelectorAll()` instead of  `getElementsByClassName()` to loop through all the `span`.

Comment: Note that the *forEach* method of [*HTMLCollections*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) is not standardised or implemented widely. It has been standardised for [*NodeList*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) but not all browsers have their HTMLCollection inherit from NodeList.

Comment: Awesome, the querySelector returns an array and you iterate through each element and apply the style.

Comment: Could you not have just looped through getElementsByClassName?

Comment: @JacobMoore, do u prefer that? let me try..

Comment: No i was just wondering, I assumed they both return an array and it would not make a difference.

Comment: @RobG What is the standard iteration method then?

Comment: @JacobMoore, some older browsers yet to support `querySelectorAll()`. In that case you can use the second example I have added with `getElementsByClassName()`.

Comment: @RobG, I have added another solution with `[].forEach(...`. Did you mention that as the standard iteration method?

Comment: @JacobMoore—the usual way was a for loop, but there is also `Array.from(list).forEach(...)` and `[].forEach.call(list, ...)` as you've done. Just remember that *getElementsByClassName* doesn't return an Array, it returns a list that which is similar to an array but doesn't have Array methods.

Comment: @RobG, thanks for helping me to improve my answer.

Answer (score 0):

this give you array try using like

```
function gridSize(){
  let size = document.getElementsByClassName("gridsquare")
    size[0].style.height = boxSize;
    size[0].style.width = boxSize; 
}
```