# javascript - modify css parent of html element

Tags: javascript, html, css

So, I have a selector which matches a `<td>`. This `<td>` inherits from a css class. Let's call it `item`.

```
item.style.backgroundImage
```

returns `""`, but

```
window.getComputedStyle(item).backgroundImage
```

returns

```
"url("http://some-url.com")"
```

I want to modify the css class so that the `backgroundImage` is something else for all inheritors.

I haven't been able to figure out how to do this! I can change the `backgroundImage` of the individual element, but I don't know how to get the class object that defines `backgroundImage`originally.

Comment: You can change the rule of the CSS that applies: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1409225/215552

Comment: Did an answer suit your question?

Answer (score 0):

Write new CSS for target class and put it in `<style>` and append it to head tag.

```js
var style = '<style>.item {background: red !important}</style>';
document.querySelector('head').innerHTML += style;
```

```css
.item {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `unset` to reset the inherited property. See the snippet below. The second cell (whose `id` is `dontInherit`) won't receive the `background-color` property.

```css
td {
  background-color: #f0f0ff;
}

td#dontInherit {
  background-color: unset;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="inherit">
      Inherited
    </td>
    <td id="dontInherit">
      Not inherited
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add one more thing to @Mohammad's answer.

If you want it for dynamic class then you can get the className and change it's style and add it to head tag.

See the Snippet below:

```js
var item = document.querySelector("#itemA");

var style = '<style>.'+item.className+' {background-image: url("https://www.beautycolorcode.com/8b0000.png") }</style>';

document.querySelector('head').innerHTML += style;
```

```css
td{
  background-image: url('https://www.beautycolorcode.com/3a4662.png');
  color:white;
  width:300px;
  height:40px;
  font-family:"Calibri";
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr><td id="itemA" class="item-A">A for Apple</td></tr>
  <tr><td class="item-B">B for Ball</td></tr>
  <tr><td class="item-C">C for Cat</td></tr>
  <tr><td class="item-A">A for Ant</td></tr>
</table>
```

You can see by default it's blue color background image. I have changed it to red color for `.item-A` class dynamically using ID selector.