# Change class property by using jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I would like to add a property directly to a class instead of objects that have given class.

It should work for dynamically added elements as well.

I tried to do it by using `$(".myElement").css("background", "green");` but it works only for already existing elements, the new elements are created with default class properties.

My code is:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>    
        <style>
            .myElement{
                width: 20px;
                height: 20px;
                background: red;
                margin: 5px;
            }
        </style>        
    </head>
        
    <body>
        <div id="elementsContainer">
            <div class="myElement"></div>
            <div class="myElement"></div>
        </div>
        <button id="addClassProperty">Add class property</button>
        <button id="addNewElement">Add new element</button>
        
        <script>
            $("#addClassProperty").click(function(){
                $(".myElement").css("background", "green");
            });
            
            $("#addNewElement").click(function(){
                $("#elementsContainer").append("<div class='myElement'></div>");
            });
        </script>
    </body> 

</html>
```

The expected result should add a new property to all existing element and to every newly created elements without cast `change property for newly created element`.

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: I copied your code into a snippit and each newly added element adds the green style when you click add class...

Comment: @dalelandry please do the following: 1) add class property, 2) create a new element.  The newly added element is red.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is far simpler by adding a class to the parent container and a corresponding css rule for `.myElement` when that class exists

```js
$("#addClassProperty").click(function() {  
  $('#elementsContainer').addClass('active')
});

$("#addNewElement").click(function() {  
  $("#elementsContainer").append("<div class='myElement'></div>");
});
```

```css
.myElement {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: red;
  margin: 5px;
}

.active .myElement {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="elementsContainer">
  <div class="myElement"></div>
  <div class="myElement"></div>
</div>
<button id="addClassProperty">Add class property</button>
<button id="addNewElement">Add new element</button>
```

Comment: @freedomn-m I changed mine while you were writing yours and posted it seconds before you did

Answer (score 0):

Rather than "change class property", you want to change/add a css rule.

EDIT: better link -->  [Changing a CSS rule-set from Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409225/changing-a-css-rule-set-from-javascript)

Or you could have one/multiple classes with existing css and change your objects' classes instead.

Answer (score 0):

When you apply a green background color to elements, the style of the background color is entered into the **style** attribute. This is how the `css()` method works. Therefore, each new element has a background color of red, taken from the css.

To solve your problem, you can use the method with adding a class, or change the color of the background rule in the **CSS itself**. This can be done using `cssRules` by referring to the `document`. Like this:

```
[...document.styleSheets[0].cssRules].find((currentSel) => (currentSel.selectorText = ".myElement")).style.background = "green";
```

By placing this code inside the click event of the selector `#addClassProperty`.

```js
$("#addClassProperty").click(function () {
    [...document.styleSheets[0].cssRules].find((currentSel) => currentSel.selectorText = ".myElement").style.background = "green";
});

$("#addNewElement").click(function () {
    $("#elementsContainer").append("<div class='myElement'></div>");
});
```

```css
.myElement {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background: red;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
        <style></style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="elementsContainer">
            <div class="myElement"></div>
            <div class="myElement"></div>
        </div>
        <button id="addClassProperty">Add class property</button>
        <button id="addNewElement">Add new element</button>
    </body>
</html>
```