# Add CSS variables (custom properties) in the root not in the document

Tags: html, css, css-variables

I am working with angular 12 and I am creating dynamic theme change.

When my application is loaded according to the selected theme I set all my color variables like this:

```
document.documentElement.style.setProperty(colorKey, colorValue);
```

After it, all colors are set to the document element not to the root element.

[image]

As you see I also have some variables to the root element. But those variables are defined in the css file as:

```
:root {
    --primary: #005d7a;
    --primary-50: #edf1f2;
    --primary-400: #0094bd;
    --primary-700: #027498;
    --secondary-50: #ffebb7;
    --silver: #3a3a3a;
    --silver-light: #e4e7ea;
    --silver-light-border: #dad7d6;
    --main-background: white;
    --main-page-background: #e4e7ea;
    --main-text-color: #3a3a3a;
    --disabled-color: #ccc;
}
```

And that works fine.

My question is:

1. How to set other variables which are defined from the ts file to the root not to the document element ?
2. According to the [post](https://www.techiediaries.com/css-root/) root selector is stronger than document. How then (as you can see on the image above) my root primary-50 color is overridden with document primary-50 ?

Comment: inline style will always win

Comment: and html is the :root element

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nothing is set on the `document`. [The `documentElement` is the root element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/documentElement).

You have a stylesheet that sets some things on [`:root`, which is the `html` element in an HTML document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:root).

i.e. `:root` in CSS targets the same element as `document.documentElement` in DOM.

---

You have some inline style (a `style` attribute) on the `html` element (which is the same element).

[Cascading rules](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity) give rules in the `style` attribute priority over all other rules of equal importance and from the same source.

The document you reference says that the selector `:root` has higher specificity that the selector `html`. Neither of them have higher specificity than a `style` attribute.

Comment: Thanks for good explanation. Whenever I read how to change value of the root CSS variable I get the same answer: document.documentElement.style.setProperty(colorKey, colorValue). That is confusing part for me. If I want to change root CSS variable is the same piece of code as adding inline CSS variable to the document element ?

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to ask now.

Comment: How to change value of (for example:) root { primary } variable I defined  in my CSS ? Without adding inline style to the document...

Comment: My whole point is that I do not want to see those style as inline style, if that is possible.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409225/changing-a-css-rule-set-from-javascript

Comment: As far as I understand according to the link you post is that changing pseudo selector rules ( :root in my case ) is not so easy/possible. The only way to do that is dynamically insert style to the document like" document.styleSheets[0].insertRule('#elid:hover { background-color: red; }', 0);  Which my differ from browser to browser ?

Comment: The selector isn't really relevant, the process for editing rules is the same regardless. APIs for changing rules are stable these days, they weren't 12 years ago.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. I think that I got the point. I will accept your answer anyway. You can add this small explanation about overriding/changing pseudo rules, if you want for someone else who read this article.