# How can I change the style of all <mark>snippets</mark> within html using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a static html file containing mostly text. Lots of text snippets are highlighted using the `<mark>` tag. I would like to add a button that toggles the text weight of the marked text snippets between bold and normal. The intended effect is to switch on / off the highlighting.

Is there any magic way to do it by directly changing the style of the `mark` css class?

Example:

- HTML: `... This is an <mark>important text snippet</mark> ...`
- CSS class BEFORE I hit the button: `mark { text-weight: bold; }`
- CSS class AFTER I hit the button: `mark { text-weight: normal; }`

The reason why I want to do this is to allow the user to decide, if he wants to see highlighted text or not. I know I can change the style of each marked text snippet, but I am wondering, if there is a more direct way.

Comment: Thanks for your answers below! Unfortunately I can only accept one, though all were very helpful in understanding the available options. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes I use this function :

```
function changeStyleProperty(ssIndex, selTxt, pName, pVal) {
    const cssRules = document.styleSheets[ssIndex].cssRules;
    for (let i = 0; i < cssRules.length; i++) {
        if (cssRules[i].selectorText === selTxt) {
            cssRules[i].style.setProperty(pName, pVal);
        }
    }
}
```

You can use `changeStyleProperty(ssIndex, 'mark', 'text-weight', 'bold')` to bold, and then `changeStyleProperty(ssIndex, 'mark', 'text-weight', 'normal')` to change back.

(If you have only one stylesheet / style block then you can just use `ssIndex=0`, otherwise you might need to check [maybe with `console.log(document.styleSheets);`] and find out which stylesheet your `mark` rule is in.)

Answer (score 3):

### Method 1 - Toggling a Class on a Parent Element

A more direct way would be to add a class to a *parent* element. Then, in CSS, you can select all of the child `mark` elements. This method saves you from iterating over every mark element on your page in JS. You could add this class on a containing `div` or even on the root `html` element if you desire.

`classList.toggle` is supported on all major browsers: https://caniuse.com/?search=classlist.toggle

```js
function toggleMarkup() {
  document.querySelector("#content").classList.toggle("markup-shown");
}
```

```css
p.markup-shown mark {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<p id="content">
Hello! This is some <mark>marked up</mark> text! And this is some more <mark>marked</mark> text.
</p>

<button onclick="toggleMarkup()">
Click me to toggle markup.
</button>
```

### Method 2 - Using CSSOM

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS_Object_Model
https://stackoverflow.com/a/55468693/9627251

You can also obtain and modify existing CSS classes directly from JS:

```
const rules = document.styleSheets.map(sheet => sheet.cssRules);
const rule = rules.find(r => r.selectorText == 'mark');
rule.style.fontWeight = 'bold'; // or normal, in your toggle function logic
```

Note that you would already have to have a CSS rule like:

```
mark { font-weight: normal; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Query all your `mark` elements, then toggle a highlight class to affect their font-weight styling. Get the parents of the mark elements using '.closest()', and add a button to each parent element.

```js
const marks = document.querySelectorAll('mark')

// use event target to get the parent element and subsequent 
// mark element and toggle a class of normal font weight
function toggleHighlight(e) {
  e.target.closest('li').querySelectorAll('mark').forEach( el => {
    el.classList.toggle('normal')
  })
}

marks.forEach(mark => {
  // create the button
  const button = document.createElement('button')
  // add text for the button
  button.textContent = 'Toggle Highlight'
  // get the parent element your mark is living within and append the button to it
  // make sure it only gets one button in case there are more than one mark element
  !mark.parentNode.innerHTML.includes('button') ? mark.parentNode.appendChild(button) : null  
  // event listener for when the button is pressed 
  button.addEventListener('click', toggleHighlight)
})
```

```css
mark {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.normal {
  font-weight: normal;
}

li {
  clear: left;
}

button {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>This is not important text</li><hr>
  <li><mark>This text here important text.</mark> But this is not. <mark>We have more important text here as well.</mark> Arcu cursus euismod quis viverra nibh cras pulvinar mattis. Tristique et egestas quis ipsum suspendisse ultrices gravida dictum. Ac turpis egestas integer eget. </li><hr>
  <li>This is text not important text. <mark>But this is</mark></li><hr>
  <li><mark>This text here important text.</mark> But this is not</li><hr>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            mark {
                font-weight: bold;
                background: none;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
<body>

This is an <mark>important text snippet</mark> and so <mark>is this</mark>.

<button onclick = "changeMark()">Change Mark Style</button>

<script>
    function changeMark() {
        document.querySelectorAll("mark").forEach(e => e.style.fontWeight = "normal");
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```