# Set a:visited style with JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How I can set a style of `a:visited` with JavaScript or jQuery. I know how to set with a regular link like

```
document.getElementById('a12').style.color = '#ff0000';
```

But I don't know how it works with `a:visited`?

Comment: Are you trying to mark a link as visited, or change the way visted links are displayed?

Comment: No, I just want to know if it possible to set style like this by using javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Style properties adjust style attributes which apply to *elements*, they completely replace *selectors*

You have two choices.

- Write your rule-sets in advance, and then design the element to match the selector.

e.g.

```
.foo:visited {
  color: #f00;
}

document.getElementById('a12').className += ' foo';
```

- Dynamically generate rule-sets with selectors that match the element.

See bobince's answer at [Setting CSS pseudo-class rules from JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311052/setting-css-pseudo-class-rules-from-javascript)

Comment: Hi, I tried a trick like

document.getElementById('tplcss').innerHTML += 'a:hover{color:#FF0000;}';

<style type="text/css" id="tplcss">
a:visited{color:#FF00FF;}
</style>

It's work on FF and Chrome, but IE got runtime error. I should follow your link. Thanks