# Add FontAwesome Icon after Visited Link

Tags: jquery, css, css-selectors

I want to add a simple **check** icon after every link that the user has visited on my website.

Here is what I have tried to so far:

**CSS**

```
.accomm-panel:visited h5:after {
    content: "\f00c";
    color: #80b54d;
}
```

Note: The ".accomm-panel" class is the anchor link. I only want to target visited links and the look for the **h5** element and attach the icon.

**JS**

```
$('.accomm-panel:visited h5').after('<i class="fa fa-check fa-1"></i>');
```

**HTML**

```
<a href="http://localhost/gbtc/accommodation/029gb-step-back-in-time/?_sfm_low_season_fee=0+10000" class="accomm-panel">
    <div class="img-container" style="background-image: url('http://localhost/gbtc/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/gordons-bay-harbour-wall-sunset.jpg');">
        <div class="price">
            <p>From</p>
            <p class="amount">R</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-content">
        <h5>Step Back in Time</h5>                                                                                           
        <p class="description">1 Guest • 12 Bedrooms • 12 Bathrooms • 029GB</p>
    </div>
</a>
```

Neither of these methods work. [This article](https://css-tricks.com/put-checkmarks-next-to-visted-links-with-pure-css/) outlines that due to user privacy issues, the suggestions in the article are unlikely to work.

I'd like to know if there's a workaround for these issues.

Comment: `:visited` is not a valid jQuery selector anyway

Comment: @haim770: it's a valid CSS selector, so it certainly should be valid under jQuery. Whether the browser returns a list of visited anchor elements is unsure (I'm currently on mobile), but that's a security issue with the browser and JavaScript, not because of an invalid selector.

Comment: @DavidThomas, No it's not. See https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/. As I see it, it wouldn't be available to the native `document.querySelectorAll` as well (for obvious privacy reasons).

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude I've added the HTML

Comment: @haim770, David Thomas: jQuery uses qSA under the hood, so any "valid" CSS selector (except namespaced ones) will work fine in qSA without causing it to throw an error. There is a huge difference between "valid" and "supported", however...

Answer (score 3):

You have to specify the font family for the ":after" pseudo element like that:

```
.accomm-panel:visited h5:after {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    text-rendering: auto;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
```

Comment: This is a valid answer. It is the same that I will respond. OP may forget javascript with this trick!

Comment: Thank you. If you read the documentation at [link] (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3A%3Aafter) this does not seem to be a requirement. FontAwesome does work on the site, as we use it for other sections.

Comment: I was trying to recreate your answer as a JSFiddle but I'm not seeing the behavior you are talking about, is this jsfiddle off in some way? http://jsfiddle.net/d4omnskw/

Comment: Yes. this is because the icons there don't have any font-family rule inherited from parent/ancestors.

Comment: @HeidarMostafa If I use ".accomm-panel h5::after" it works on all links. As soon as I make it ".accomm-panel:visited h5::after" does it stop working altogether.

Comment: actually this will work with any pseudo selector except :visited as modern browsers restricted :visited styling to few properties such as color, background-color... for security reasons, read more about it here : https://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/03/privacy-related-changes-coming-to-css-vistited/

for visited you'll have to use JavaScript. sadly there is no work rounds.

Answer (score 0):

Heres a quick example using `.click` could this work for you? As far as i know you cant target pseudo css selectors

all its doing is just adding the active class on click. I'll try tweaking it a little bit

http://codepen.io/noobskie/pen/VLgmyG

*edit* Also here's more info on styling visited links with jquery [How to set link visited color in JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7030289/how-to-set-link-visited-color-in-jquery)

*edit* just seen the updated html @Heidar Mostafa answer works better

Answer (score 0):

Did you use `header` in `link`?
I prefer  `link` in `header`, then you can follow [this article](https://css-tricks.com/put-checkmarks-next-to-visted-links-with-pure-css/)

```
.accomm-panel:visited:after {
  content: "\f00c";
  color: #80b54d;
}
```

BTW, in your case... Uhm! I don't think `:before` pseudo work in `:visited` pseudo

```css
.accomm-panel:visited {
  color: red;
}

.accomm-panel:visited h5 {
  color: #80b54d;
}

.accomm-panel:visited h5:after {
  content: "test";
}
```

```html
<a href="/sample.html" class="accomm-panel">
 <h5>This is a link</h5>
</a>
```