# using a:hover to change the color of an image

Tags: html, css, href

In the following example, a mouse hover over each link changes the image:

http://www.prism.gatech.edu/~dm257/sprite.html

The trick is the following line of code:

```
#home a:hover {
  background: transparent url('sprite.png') 0px -37px no-repeat;
}
```

The a:hover selector sets the background to a green part of of sprite.png.

Can I do the same thing with a:visited? Make the icon turn green after the user has clicked it?

I changed a:hover to a:visited and nothing happens.

Comment: the `a:visited` is when the page as been visited by the user, user `a:active` to change the image when the user clicked on it.

Comment: write a:active instead of a:visited check this http://jsfiddle.net/3rj8g/

Comment: see  joelin.org/sprite.html, I tried that idea but the icons are not highlighting after clicking on them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Styling of `:visited` is currently limited to prevent security risk related to exposing user's browsing history:

https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/%3Avisited:

> Starting in Firefox 4, major limitations to the styles you can apply
>   using this selector have been introduced. For more information on the
>   limitations and the motivation for them, see [Privacy and the :visited
>   selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Privacy_and_the_%3Avisited_selector).
>   The same limitations have been adopted by other browsers, including
>   Safari 5/4.1 and Chrome 6.

Answer (score 0):

You absolutely can. Of course, the `:visited` state will only be visible upon the next load of the page. Browsers are able to determine whether or not a page has been previously accessed via header information.

Here's a jsFiddle that demonstrates the proper declaration order with helpful comments:

- http://jsfiddle.net/fmYdD/4/

Comment: It didn't seem to work, at http://joelin.org/sprite.html I have `#home a:hover` followed by `#home a:active` and finally `#home a:visited`. View the source and click on the css file.

Comment: the best i can say right now is that the visited state is not being passed into the page when i click on one of those links (the links just point back to the same page)...perhaps its being cached?

Answer (score 0):

you can accomplish with the help of this plugin - [Visited links plugin](http://remysharp.com/2008/02/25/visited-plugin/)

Download JS: [jQuery.visited.js](http://remysharp.com/downloads/jquery.visited.js)

See below lins which is related:

- [set a:visited style with javascript or jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3478779/set-avisited-style-with-javascript-or-jquery)
- [Setting CSS pseudo-class rules from JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311052/setting-css-pseudo-class-rules-from-javascript)

Comment: i tried it and somehow the visited function is never being called...if i change visited to clicked (standard jquery), then i do catch it..