# Enable/disable hover style at runtime?

Tags: jquery

In my css I have this:

```
#panel li:hover {
  background-color: #ffa;
}
```

under some condition I'd like to disable to hover style from the li items, something like:

```
function start() {
    $('#panel li').ignoreHoverRules();
}
```

and re-enable it later:

```
function end() {
    $('#panel li').reenableHoverRules();
}
```

is something like that possible? Not sure how to 'enable' or 'disable' the hover style rules at runtime,

Thanks

Answer (score 10):

Definitely the easiest way to do this is add a class to your `<li>` elements:

```
#panel li.allowHover:hover {
  background-color: #ffa;
}
```

```
function start() {
    $('#panel li').removeClass("allowHover");
}
function end() {
    $('#panel li').addClass("allowHover");
}
```

Otherwise, you get into very awkward territory with manipulating CSS rules - [it's no easy task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311052/setting-css-pseudo-class-rules-from-javascript/311437#311437).