# Pseudo-element CSS dynamically using JavaScript

Tags: jquery, html, css, pseudo-element

Is it possible to set the CSS of a pseudo-element dynamically? For example:

**jQuery dynamically styling help container**

```
$('#help').css({
    "width" : windowWidth - xOffset,
    "height" : windowHeight - yOffset,
    "bottom" : -windowHeight,
    "left" : 200
});
```

**jQuery Attempt at setting the inner border of the help container:**

```
$('#help:before').css({
    "width" : windowWidth - xOffset,
    "height" : windowHeight - yOffset
});
```

**CSS file for the above**

```
#help
{
    opacity: 0.9;
    filter:alpha(opacity=90);   
    -moz-opacity: 0.9;          
    z-index: 1000000;
    bottom: -550px;
    left: 400px;
    background-color: #808080;
    border: 5px dashed #494949;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
    border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;        
}
#help:before 
{
    border: 5px solid white;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
    border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;          
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting CSS pseudo-class rules from JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/311052/setting-css-pseudo-class-rules-from-javascript)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do it directly through jQuery.

Look at this question: [Setting CSS pseudo-class rules from JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311052/setting-css-pseudo-class-rules-from-javascript)

[@Box9's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311052/setting-css-pseudo-class-rules-from-javascript/5077782#5077782) is probably the one you should actually use:

> I threw together a [small library for this](https://github.com/Box9/jss) since I do think there
>   are valid use cases for manipulating stylesheets in JS.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than setting the width and height using `.css()`, you should just use `.width()` and `height()` directly.

Comment: Can you post the code for this, my code doesn't work:
        $('#help:before').width(windowHeight - 410)
                         .height(windowHeight - 210);