# How to change css pseudo elements in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, pseudo-element

i want to change below `:before` css pseudo element's `top` value  via javascript or jQuery dynamically ... how can i do it?

```
#buble{

height:70px;
width:980px;
background-color:#bce5a5;
display:none;
-moz-border-radius:5px;
-webkit-border-radius:5px;
border-radius:5px;
box-shadow:0px 0px 4px #dadada;
text-indent:35px;
color:#4a8f44;
font-weight:bold;
font-size:14pt;

       }

#buble:before{

content:"";           
display:block;
position:absolute;
top:77px; /* value = - border-top-width - border-bottom-width */
left:555px; /* controls horizontal position */
border-width:11px 7px 0px; /* vary these values to change the angle of the vertex */
border-style:solid;
border-color:#bce5a5 transparent;
width:0;
height:0;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7164709/pseudo-element-css-dynamically-using-javascript

Comment: Simple answer you can't but there are workarounds

Comment: @user3509090 What is value it would be set to ? From `77px` to what value ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my knowledge you can not modify pseudo style directly, but you can insert the **CSS** to the **head portion** of the **DOM** by this way,

#### jQuery

```
$( "div" ).click(function() {

  $('<style>p:before{top:10px}</style>').appendTo('head');

});
```

#### Check this <kbd>**[Demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/58qmF/)**</kbd>

Comment: didn't you see my answer?

Comment: @ C-link i saw..thank you so much , spend your valuable time for answer my question

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery you need to append style in the head:

```
$('<style>#buble:before{top: 50px}</style>').appendTo('head');
```

[see more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22600566/how-to-apply-the-css-for-before-and-after-pseudo-classes)