# A Tag active Attribute

Tags: css, anchor

Can I toggle the 'active' status of an  element to invoke css `a:active` properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you hold your mouse down on the anchor element (or any element), it will invoke the active property. If you want to do this dynamically (in JavaScript), you can create a class, `a.active`, and add/remove `"active"` from the className property on the dom element.

Comment: What I am looking to do is 'read' the fact that the link is active or not.  'Invoke' the a:active style by simulating a click on the link.

Comment: Answer is no, found this thread...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/311052/setting-css-pseudo-class-rules-from-javascript