# color picker code

Tags: javascript, color-picker

I have this code to change the color of elements like the Background-color,text color,active link color,visited link color etc. inside a div. I have to enter the color for each in the text-boxes and accordingly the color of background,text color,link colors would change. This is the program objective. 
 But I can't change the colors of the active, followed and visited links. How to do that with only HTML, CSS and JavaScript? Please don't tell me any method using jQuery, as I don't know jQuery. I only want it it with JavaScript.

```
 <html>
     <head>
     </head>
     <body>
         <script>
             function fun()
             {
                 var bg=document.getElementById("t1").value;
                 var txt=document.getElementById("t2").value;
                 var al=document.getElementById("t3").value;
                 var vl=document.getElementById("t4").value;
                 var hv=document.getElementById("t5").value;
                 document.getElementById("dv").style.backgroundColor=bg;
                 document.getElementById("dv").style.alinkcolor=txt;
                 document.getElementById("dv").style.vlinkcolor=al;
                 document.getElementById("dv").style.color=vl;
                 document.getElementById("dv").style.color=hv;
             }
         </script>
         <h1>Enter Colors: </h1>
         Background: <input type="text" id="t1" name="txt1">
         <br/><br/>
         Text:  <input type="text" id="t2" name="txt2">
         <br/><br/>
         Link:  <input type="text" id="t3" name="link">
         <br/><br/>
         Active Link: <input type="text" id="t4" name="alink">
         <br/><br/>
         Followed Link: <input type="text" id="t5" name="vlink">
         <br/><br/>
         <input type="button" value="test" onclick="fun();">
         <br/><br/>
         <div id="dv">&nbsp;hello
             This is a Test<br/>
             You Have Selected These Colors<br/>
             <a href="#">This is a Test Link</a><br/>
         </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/311052/setting-css-pseudo-class-rules-from-javascript

Comment: no my problem is a little different

Answer (score 0):

I Updated your code by assigning the ID's to the elements. Here is the updated code. Try this code to see if it helps. Thanks.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
     <script>
         function fun()
         {
             var bg=document.getElementById("t1").value;
             var txt=document.getElementById("t2").value;
             var al=document.getElementById("t3").value;
             var vl=document.getElementById("t4").value;
             var hv=document.getElementById("t5").value;
             document.getElementById("dv").style.backgroundColor=bg;
             document.getElementById("link").style.alinkcolor=al;
             document.getElementById("link").style.vlinkcolor=vl;
             document.getElementById("para").style.color=txt;
             document.getElementById("link").style.color=hv;
         }
     </script>
     <h1>Enter Colors: </h1>
     Background: <input type="text" id="t1" name="txt1">
     <br/><br/>
     Text:  <input type="text" id="t2" name="txt2">
     <br/><br/>
     Link:  <input type="text" id="t3" name="link">
     <br/><br/>
     Active Link: <input type="text" id="t4" name="alink">
     <br/><br/>
     Followed Link: <input type="text" id="t5" name="vlink">
     <br/><br/>
     <input type="button" value="test" onclick="fun();">
     <br/><br/>
     <div id="dv">&nbsp;
       <p id="para">hello This is a Test<br/>
         You Have Selected These Colors<br/><p>
         <a id="link" href="#">This is a Test Link</a><br/>
     </div>
```