# Is it possible to fade in newly created elements using only css3?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working with a chat script. **I have no control over any javascript, only CSS.** I was wondering if it is possible to get the posts to fade in, as they are added, with only CSS3.

**Here is a simplified example of the chat script:**

http://jsfiddle.net/CF4pj/1/

```
<a class="click" href="#/">click</a>

<div class="stuff"></div>

<script>

$("a.click").click(function() {
    $("div.stuff").append("<div class='lol'>text text text text text</div>");
});

</script>
```

Is there any CSS3 (only CSS3, no javascript) I could add to the script above to make the new "posts" fade in?

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS transition fade in](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11660710/css-transition-fade-in)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here you go...

```
div.click {
    background:yellow;
    display:inline;
}
div.lol {
    padding:5px;
    border:1px solid green;
    margin:5px 0;
    animation: fadein 2s;
    -moz-animation: fadein 2s;
    /* Firefox */
    -webkit-animation: fadein 2s;
    /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-animation: fadein 2s;
    /* Opera */
}
@keyframes fadein {
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes fadein {
    /* Firefox */
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
    /* Safari and Chrome */
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@-o-keyframes fadein {
    /* Opera */
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

Check out this fiddle...[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CF4pj/4/)

Comment: Pay attention, maybe your component need a `display: block` to be working with the animation

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
<code>
    .lol {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transition: opacity 2s ease-in;
        -moz-transition: opacity 2s ease-in;
        -o-transition: opacity 2s ease-in;
        -ms-transition: opacity 2s ease-in;
        transition: opacity 2s ease-in;
    }​
</code>
```

Comment: this does not work, because a new element does not _transform_ it's css attributes, it would simply start with the given opacity