# Animation: Fade in when creating an element and fade out when deleting

Tags: javascript, html, css, fade

I'm having trouble with the following situation.

I have a button which acts like a normal toggle. When I click on the "Animate" button, I want the `<p>This is new Div</p>` to fade in when I again click on the `Animate` button, this `<p>` should fade out.

How can I achieve this?

```js
const main = document.getElementById('main');
const btn = document.getElementById('btn');

let show = false;
btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if(show) {
    const newDiv = document.getElementById("new-div");
    newDiv.remove();
    show = false;
  } else {
    const newDiv = document.createElement('div');
    newDiv.id = "new-div";
    newDiv.innerHTML = "<p>This is new Div</p>";
    main.appendChild(newDiv);
    show = true;
  }
})
```

```css
#new-div {
  transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <button id="btn">Animate</button>
</div>
```

I'm actually building a gallary layout app, which requires to fade in when clicked on a image + show in full screen, then fade out to its original position when clicked. Since there will be many images, I want to use JS to dynamically work on this.

And the biggest hurdle so far is to implement `fade-out`, because the element is being deleted.

Comment: where is your animation?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS transition fade in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11660710/css-transition-fade-in)

Comment: @OmriAttiya, I couldn't think of any proper animation, so didn't include it. And no the above mentioned question doesn't answer my question, I'm looking for both `fade in` and `fade out` implementation

Comment: It's the same since you use it for all transitions. Read more about transitions and how they work

Comment: I've found a potential solution for this problem: https://jsfiddle.net/0g5cbun6/ But what is the support of `animationend` event listener for browsers? I'm not understanding what https://caniuse.com says

Comment: WebKit has another event for this, pls check out https://jsfiddle.net/Kenvdb/8nsbp16o/

Answer (score 2):

Based on your information I've made a refined version, pls see fiddle and code below: https://jsfiddle.net/Kenvdb/8nsbp16o/

JavaScript:

```
const main = document.getElementById('main');
const btn = document.getElementById('btn');

let toggledDiv = null;

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (!toggledDiv) {
    show();
  } else {
    hide();
  }
})

const show = () => {
  toggledDiv = document.createElement('div');
  toggledDiv.id = "content";
  toggledDiv.style.opacity = "1";
  toggledDiv.innerHTML = "<p>This is new Div</p>";

  main.appendChild(toggledDiv);
}

const hide = () => {
  toggledDiv.style.animation = "fade-out 0.5s ease-in";
  toggledDiv.style.opacity = "0";
  toggledDiv.addEventListener('animationend', remove);
  toggledDiv.addEventListener('webkitAnimationEnd', remove);
}

const remove = () => {
  toggledDiv.remove();
  toggledDiv = null;
};
```

CSS:

```
#content {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: fade-in 0.5s ease-in;
}

@keyframes fade-in {
    0% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 1; }
}

@keyframes fade-out {
    0% { opacity: 1; }
    100% { opacity: 0; }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="main">
  <button id="btn">Animate</button>
</div>
```

Comment: how is this answer the question?

Comment: Hey, I'm actually building a gallary app, which requires the above unique problem statement. I want to add and delete my `div` through JS and add animation to it

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set the opacity to 0 first.  Then you can apply a keyframe animation. 
Otherwise, the element has nothing to transition from.

See below.

```
#new-div {
  opacity: 1;
  animation: fadeIn 2s ease-in-out;

}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey, I got this already. The problem is how do you implement the `fade out` now? Since the element is deleted(see my JS code), the animation seems not to work for fade out.

Answer (score 0):

There's several ways of doing this. You can set the opacity of the newly added element using the `style` attribute:

```js
const main = document.getElementById('main');
const btn = document.getElementById('btn');

let show = false;
let fading = false;
btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (fading) return;
  if (show) {
    const newDiv = document.getElementById("new-div");
    newDiv.style = "opacity: 0"; // start the fade
    fading = true;
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      fading = false; // disable showing/hiding while fading
      newDiv.remove(); // remove after fade completed
      show = false;
    }, 2000);
  } else {
    show = true;
    const newDiv = document.createElement('div');
    newDiv.id = "new-div";
    newDiv.innerHTML = "<p>This is new Div</p>";
    main.appendChild(newDiv);
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      newDiv.style = "opacity: 1"; // Start fading after a minimal time
    });
  }
})
```

```css
#new-div {
  transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <button id="btn">Animate</button>
</div>
```

Or you can use jQuery, which significantly reduce the code:

```js
$("#btn").on('click', () => {
  var newDiv = $("#new-div");
  if (newDiv.length) {
    newDiv.stop().fadeOut(2000, function() {
      newDiv.remove();
    });
  } else {
    $(`<div id='new-div'>
       <p>This is new Div</p>
       </div`).appendTo("#main").hide().fadeIn(2000);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
  <button id="btn">Animate</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, BTW in your vanilla JS answer, the fade out animation is only working. What I need is both - fade in and fade out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm want to implement this in vanilla JS.

Comment: I've found a potential solution for this problem: https://jsfiddle.net/0g5cbun6 ,  could you help me with support of `animationend` event listener?

Answer (score -1):

You can do it simply using both of `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()` methods in jQuery.
Here is an example:

```js
let alreadyClicked = false;

$("#btn").click(function() {
   if(alreadyClicked == false) {
      $("p").remove(); //Remove the paragraph if already created.
      $("#main").append("<p style='display: none;'>Hello, world!</p>"); //Create a paragraph.
      $("p").fadeIn(); //Show it by fading it in.
      alreadyClicked = true;
   } else {
      $("p").fadeOut();  //Fade it out
      alreadyClicked = false;
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
  <button id="btn">Animate</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Why should you use a large library to only fade in / out a div?

Comment: @KennyDope Is jQuery a large library?!

Comment: Yes, for only fading it is, imho you should always consider the amount of code and size added to a http request..

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mention, I am looking for vanilla JS answers. Thanks by the way.

Comment: @cdadityang Are you really looking for VanillaJS anwser?

Comment: @MARSHMALLOW, yes, I'm actually learning to build an photo gallary layout in Vanilla CSS and VanillaJS.