# Are there mechanics in Javascript that can only be emitted by a real user?

Tags: javascript, validation, events

I would like to find an interaction in Javascript that only a human can do, but javascript can track it if the user has done it.

Something like an only readable event but not writable.

Comment: What's the problem you're trying to solve? In some devices the `orientationChange` event read-only, if that helps?

Comment: That's what a captcha is for. :)

Comment: Are you somehow trying to prevent selenium driver or some related technology? This would not prevent user scripts, nor crawlers, although you could make their lives more difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use mouse-driven CSS pseudoclasses; I don't believe they can be triggered using Javascript: see [Trigger css hover with JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4347116/trigger-css-hover-with-js) for a little more information.

If you set some style aspect on the hover, for example, you might be able to detect that using javascript.

I don't know how well this approach would work cross-browser however, and you might need to use a visible element.

see also [Activate an element's :active CSS pseudo-class using Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8101854/activate-an-elements-active-css-pseudo-class-using-javascript)