# How to change class when button fires active event

Tags: jquery

How can I change class on a button when it fires active event?

Something like:

```
$("#invitation button").mouseover(function() {
    $(this).addClass("ui-state-hover");
}).mouseout(function() {
    $(this).removeClass("ui-state-hover");
});
```

but for the 'active' event.

Comment: what do you mean by active? seems to be same as click event

Comment: There is no active event. Do you mean focus?

Comment: Do you mean CSS pseudo class :active ?

Comment: @roasted Yes, I mean the same event that is applied when is used this pseudo class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Much cleaner:

```
$("#invitation").on('mousedown mouseup', 'button', function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("your-class");
});
```

See documentation for `on()` at http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Just for clarification, it seems to be impossible to trigger the actual `DOMActive` state described in the spec. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8101854/activate-an-elements-active-css-pseudo-class-using-javascript#comment10044626_8102096

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#invitation button").mouseover(function() {
    $(this).addClass("ui-state-hover");
});
$("#invitation button").mouseout(function() {
    $(this).removeClass("ui-state-hover");
});
```

Change class on active(click)

```
$("#invitation button").mousedown(function() {
    $(this).addClass("your-class");
});
$("#invitation button").mouseup(function() {
    $(this).removeClass("your-class");
});
```