# Creating CSS :after with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I need to dynamically create my CSS styles for my elements. However, I need to have :after in CSS and I have heard that you cannot modify this in jQuery.

Is this true? Is there anyway around this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can generate a `<style>` tag and insert it into the `<head>`:

http://jsfiddle.net/PrBHF/

```
$("head").append($('<style>div:after { content: " World" }</style>'));
```

Comment: This does not work in all browsers, specially Internet Explorer.

Comment: There are alternative methods here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/311052/setting-css-pseudo-class-rules-from-javascript

Comment: @ShankarSangoli: This answer works in IE8/9. It doesn't work in any lower version due to `:after` not being supported.

Comment: Regarding browser support: Since the question is about `:after` to begin with, it's implicit that browser support is not part of the question/answer.

Comment: @ShankarSangoli call me whatever you want but I stopped caring about Internet Explorer simply not doing what usually works well in all other browsers. Especially old versions. If people still use IE6 and still ride bicycle without helmet, let them. I don't care anymore.

Answer (score 6):

Why create css using javascrript?

Have the required styles in a css class and then apply the class using jQuery by using `addClass` method.

Answer (score 5):

> Is this true?

Yes. Pseudo-elements created with `:after` are not part of the DOM and therefore cannot be selected.

> Is there anyway around this?

No. Unless you do it without `:after` (use an actual element, then you can select it/bind events to it).

**Edit**

Having re-read your question, I think you're actually asking if you can apply `:after` styles to an element with jQuery. The answer is still no, although you can use `addClass` to add a new class to the element and define `:after` styles for that class name.

**Edit again**

When I've said "no", it seems I'm not entirely correct... see @AtesGorals answer for a nice workaround.