# Is there any way to reset :after/:before CSS rules for an element?

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome

Is there any way to (robustly) reset any possible `:after` and `:before` CSS rules for a newly created element?

Usually you can just set the style rules you want to reset on the element directly (with `!important` if you want to be sure), but I don't know of any way of changing rules defined in `:after` on the element only.

(Only has to work with Chrome, if at all possible.)

---

An **example** at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/84kZK/).

The content added with the `:before`/`:after` rules is affecting the value returned by `clientHeight`.

Comment: also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/manipulating-css-before-and-after-pseudo-elements-using-jquery

Comment: @primatology, well, seems that BoltClock answered it there: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5041526/107152 But maybe Chrome has some special way of accessing/modifying those?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting CSS pseudo-class rules from JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/311052/setting-css-pseudo-class-rules-from-javascript)

Comment: @Pumbaa80, I'm not quite satisfied with any of those answers, though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a [DOM2 API](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Style/css.html#CSS-DocumentCSS) for that matter. The correct way to do this is

```
document.getOverrideStyle(p, ':after').display = 'none'; // or
document.getOverrideStyle(p, ':after').cssText = 'display: none !important;';
```

Unfortunately, no browser has implemented it. ([Webkit returns null](http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebCore/dom/Document.cpp#L3811), [Firefox has no such method](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=45424)). It looks like CSS3 doesn't even bother talking about that anymore, maybe because the usecases are very rare.

So you're gonna have to do some id/className magic as suggested [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9798289/27862) or in the [other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/311437/27862)

Comment: Good to know there is (was?) a thought out API for this, too bad it's not implemented. Good sources, +1.

Comment: Firefox tracks [this bug for implementing `getOverrideStyle`](//bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=45424): opened 21 years ago, inactive for the last 3 years (at least 7 years if you don’t count the automatic bot that reduced the bug’s priority).

Answer (score 2):

I'd just assign a class name to the new elements that does not have `:before` / `:after` content.

Example - http://jsfiddle.net/84kZK/1/

Comment: It would work, but I'd have to check that the class is not used anywhere else (currently or in the future), making it less reliable (theoretically that is). I was hoping for something (in)directly accessible via the element, e.g `elem.beforeStyle` would be great. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Ah, okay. You can write new CSS that resets the offending `:before`/`:after` pseudo-elements:

```
function resetPsuedo(el) {
    if (!el.id) el.id = makeId();
    var selector = "#" + el.id;

    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
    style = document.createElement('style'),
    rules = document.createTextNode(selector + ":before, " + selector + ":after { content: '' }");

    style.type = 'text/css';
    if(style.styleSheet)
        style.styleSheet.cssText = rules.nodeValue;
    else style.appendChild(rules);
    head.appendChild(style);
}

function makeId() {
    var text = "";
    var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

    for (var i=0; i < 15; i++)
        text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));

    return text;
}
```

​Assigning a random ID to the element you pass in (if it doesn't have one) allows you to hack-up inline styles—rather than accessing `el.beforeStyle`, you can use CSS selectors: `el#rkhjr828t9g:before`.

You may need to add more rules to fully reset the styles. **jsFiddle:** [view me!](http://jsfiddle.net/EHPFD/5/)

---

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#before-after-content

> ​The :before and :after pseudo-elements interact with other boxes as
>   if they were real elements inserted just inside their associated
>   element.
>
> For example, the following document fragment and style sheet:
>
> ```
> <p> Text </p>                   p:before { display: block; content: 'Some'; }
> ```
>
> ...would render in exactly the same way as the following document
>   fragment and style sheet:
>
> ```
> <p><span>Some</span> Text </p>  span { display: block }
> ```
>
> Similarly, the following document fragment and style sheet:
>
> ```
> <h2> Header </h2>     h2:after { display: block; content: 'Thing'; }
> ```
>
> ...would render in exactly the same way as the following document
>   fragment and style sheet:
>
> ```
> <h2> Header <span>Thing</span></h2>   h2 { display: block; }
>                                       span { display: block; }
> ```

Comment: No they don't seem to create any DOM elements according to http://stackoverflow.com/a/5041526/107152

Comment: @Qtax, though they don't add any elements *accessible* to the DOM, they behave just like child `spans` added to the element. See edits.

Comment: That would also affect other elements for which these rules apply, which is not desired.

Comment: @Qtax, randomly-generated IDs will do the trick :). Just pass in the element and the function will take care of the rest.

I know this is far from ideal, but it's the best we've got.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ruleSelector("ref::before")[0].style` instead of `document.getOverrideStyle(ref, ':before')`.

http://jsfiddle.net/s3fv8e5v/4/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>CSS</title>

<style>
    body {
        font: 200%/1.45 charter;
    }
    ref::before {
        content: '\00A7';
        letter-spacing: .1em;
    }
</style>

<article>The seller can, under Business Law <ref>1782</ref>, offer a full refund to buyers. </article>

<script>
    function ruleSelector(selector) {
        function uni(selector) {
            return selector.replace(/::/g, ':') // for Firefox
        }
        return Array.prototype.filter.call(Array.prototype.concat.apply([], Array.prototype.map.call(document.styleSheets, function(x) {
            return Array.prototype.slice.call(x.cssRules);
        })), function(x) {
            return uni(x.selectorText) === uni(selector);
        });
    }

    var toggle = false, 
        pseudo = ruleSelector("ref::before").slice(-1);

    document.querySelector("article").onclick = function() {
        pseudo.forEach(function(rule) {
            if (toggle = !toggle)
                rule.style.color = "red";
            else
                rule.style.color = "black";
        });
    }
</script>
```