# Undo pseudo element ::before and ::after rules

Tags: css, pseudo-element

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any way to reset :after/:before CSS rules for an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9798210/is-there-any-way-to-reset-after-before-css-rules-for-an-element)

Is there a neat way to undo all ::before and ::after pseudo element rules on an element? I want to remove the arrow effect on a dropdown menu which is using Twitter bootstrap styles. Do I have to unset each rule one by one or can it be cleared any other way? E.g

```
.navbar .nav > li > .dropdown-menu::after {
position: absolute;
top: -6px;
left: 10px;
display: inline-block;
border-right: 6px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 6px solid white;
border-left: 6px solid transparent;
content: '';
}
```

Comment: How about setting display: none; or display: none!important;?

Comment: You should be able to just set `content:none;` and there won't be anything for CSS to style.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/LQTmF/

```
<selector>:after{
    content:none;
}
```

Comment: Ah, that works. I thought none would be the equivalent to "", which it was already set to, but no :) Thanks

Comment: `none` is the CSS equivalent of `NULL`. An empty string is still a string, is it not? ;)

Comment: This is very true, i should know better :( *hangs head*