# Trying to get content value of icon font

Tags: javascript, pseudo-element

I am using web icon font and I am trying to get the content of `:before` pseudo selector like below

```
 var ele = document.querySelector('.flaticon-fishing2');
 var beforeEle = ele.previousSibling;
 // Now befpreEle does not seem to have anything.
 // I want to get the binary content code value of before element
```

I have tried this too

```
 var content = window.getComputedStyle(
document.querySelector('.flaticon-fishing2'), ':before'
 ).getPropertyValue('content');
```

It is trying to display icon, but not giving the content.

Is there any way to get this?

Comment: As far as I'm aware there is no way to access the before/after pseudo-elements (but I could easily be wrong). It seems that your design is mixing display with logic, which is usually a bad thing; maybe you should re-think your structure.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any way to reset :after/:before CSS rules for an element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9798210/is-there-any-way-to-reset-after-before-css-rules-for-an-element)

Comment: @Dave A straight question to your smart comment, if you can prove any of those solutions are working for my requirement, I will vote to close my question.

Comment: OK, settle down; I meant no offence. The question I marked as a possible duplicate is trying to do a very similar thing (access before/after via JavaScript), but as you can see from the answer, while the capability was part of the DOM2 spec, it was never implemented and has now been dropped. Personally I see that as a good indication that what you're trying to do is impossible.

Answer (score 1):

You can get access the pseudo elements using `window.getComputedStyle`, like this:

```
var content = window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('#ii'), ':before').getPropertyValue('content');
```

Here is a **[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Karim_AG/SnqcH/1/)**