# Check if pseudo class exists in element with pure js / cross-browser solution(:after,:before, ...)

Tags: javascript, html, css

first of all thanks to everyone who is willing to help me.
My problem is quite big, so basically i want a method, that could identify all current pseudo names on my given HTML element. Then check what CSS styles were added or modified through those pseudo classes and append them to new HTML element. All this should be on pure JS and cross-browser as much as possible.

Part of this problem i solved myself, but i don't have enough knowledge of javascript or imagination to finish this and can't find any good examples of similar solutions at least partially.

```
    constructor() {
        this._options = {
            pseudoElements: ['active', 'checked', 'disabled', 'empty', 'enabled', 'first-child', 'first-of-type', 'focus', 'hover', 'in-range', 'invalid', 'last-child', 'last-of-type', 'link', 'not(*)', 'nth-child(*)', 'nth-last-child(*)', 'only-of-type', 'only-child', 'optional', 'out-of-range', 'read-only', 'read-write', 'required', 'root', 'target', 'valid', 'visited', 'after', 'before']
        }
    }

    _handleElmCss(domElm, newElm) {
        // could not think any better solution then getting all CSS without pseudo then checking with pseudo the same Style object difference. I need as fast as possible way, because i am working with hundred of thousands elements.
        var computedStyle = getComputedStyle(domElm);
              for (var i = 0, len = this._options.pseudoElements.length; i < len; i++) {
                    var pseu_name = this._options.pseudoElements[i];
                    if (this._containsPseudo(domElm, ':' + pseu_name)) {
                        var differentParameters = this._getComputedDifference(pseu_name, computedStyle, domElm);
                        console.log(differentParameters);
                    }
                };
      }

        _getComputedDifference(pseu_name, computed2, domElm) {
            var computed1 = getComputedStyle(domElm, ':' + pseu_name);
            var array1 = [], array2 = [];
            // I belive there is a faster way to convert getComputedStyle to key-value array.
            for (var i = 0; i < computed1.length; i++) {
                var key = computed1[i];
                var value = computed1.getPropertyValue(key);
                if (key != "" && key != null) {
                    array1[i] = value; // i believe this part is incorrect, i mean array-key should be the "key" variable, but i get JS errors.
                }
            }
            for (var i = 0; i < computed2.length; i++) {
                var key = computed2[i];
                var value = computed2.getPropertyValue(key);
                if (key != "" && key != null) {
                    array2[i] = value; // i believe this part is incorrect, i mean array-key should be the "key" variable, but i get JS errors.
                }
            }
            return array1.filter(val => !array2.includes(val));
        }

    _containsPseudo(node, selector) {
        // this method works only with :empty, :hover and so on. :before and :after does not work.
        var nativeMatches = (node.matches || node.msMatchesSelector);
        try {
            return(nativeMatches.call(node, selector));
        } catch (error) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

This code is copied from my library and may contain some missing parts or type errors.

Originaly by this post title i need help with checking if any given element contains any pseudo class or not, but if someone knows solution to other my problems mentioned above, please free to comment. Thank you.

Parts that this script should do by my imagination(I may be wrong):

1. Check if current element contains any pseudo classes.
2. Get current pseudo classes order(so CSS should not be overwritten incorrectly).
3. foreach current pseudo classes and get current style that was modified, added from any CSS source.
4. Add new combined style(only that changed in pseudo elements) to new element.

Comment: You seem to have pseudo-classes and pseudo-elements mixed up. Your title refers to pseudo-elements, but your code contains strings for both kinds. And you use both terms interchangeably when they are two distinct concepts. Your code and question are fundamentally flawed for this reason.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [getComputedStyle()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) [(W3C Reference)](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Style/css.html#CSS-CSSStyleSheet) with second param `pseudoElt` to get it.
Check this example:

```js
var el = document.querySelector('#elt'),
pseudo = window.getComputedStyle(el, ':before');
alert(pseudo.getPropertyValue("content"));
```

```css
#elt:before {
 content: "This element has pseudo class"
}
```

```html
<div id="elt"></div>
```

**EDIT**

You may like to see this in action:([function from another so answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27707831/3709086))

```
<style>
#elt {
    color:red;
}
#elt2 {
    color:blue;
}
#elt:before {
}
#elt2:first-child {
}
#elt2:after {
}
</style>

<div id="elt">#ELT1</div>
<div id="elt2">#ELT2</div>
<div id="container"></div>
<hr>
<script type="text/javascript">


function ruleSelector(selector) {
    function uni(selector) {
        return selector.replace(/::/g, ':')
    }
    return Array.prototype.filter.call(Array.prototype.concat.apply([], Array.prototype.map.call(document.styleSheets, function(x) {
        return Array.prototype.slice.call(x.cssRules);
    })), function(x) {
        return uni(x.selectorText) === uni(selector);
    });
}

lists = {pseudos: ['active', 'checked', 'disabled', 'empty', 'enabled', 'first-child', 'first-of-type', 'focus', 'hover', 'in-range', 'invalid', 'last-child', 'last-of-type', 'link', 'not(*)', 'nth-child(*)', 'nth-last-child(*)', 'only-of-type', 'only-child', 'optional', 'out-of-range', 'read-only', 'read-write', 'required', 'root', 'target', 'valid', 'visited', 'after', 'before']};

document.write("<h1>#elt</h1>");
for (var i = 0, len = lists.pseudos.length; i < len; i++) {
    var pseudo = lists.pseudos[i];
    if(ruleSelector("#elt:"+pseudo).length)
        document.write("<strong>#elt has :"+pseudo+"</strong><br>");
    else
        document.write("<small>#elt hasn't :"+pseudo+"</small><br>");
}

document.write("<h1>#elt2</h1>");
for (var i = 0, len = lists.pseudos.length; i < len; i++) {
    var pseudo = lists.pseudos[i];
    if(ruleSelector("#elt2:"+pseudo).length)
        document.write("<strong>#elt2 has :"+pseudo+"</strong><br>");
    else
        document.write("<small>#elt2 hasn't :"+pseudo+"</small><br>");
}

</script>
```

I've just adapted the code, as you can do too. Enjoy.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer, please correct if i am wrong, but as i can see you only get pseudo element parameter that you know exists("content"). As i tested with getComputedStyle i can see that it returns many many parameters if you give it existing pseudo name or not, so in short, this does not identify if pseudo name exists or not, it just returns very specific pseudo element that is already know that exists. 
I use similar technique in my code above,i filter difference between two arrays(with pseudo and without pseudo). But this solution is not a good one and costs memory.

Comment: Yep, you're right. And getComputedStyle doesn't cost lots of memory.

Comment: Please analyze my code, specially the _getComputedDifference method as you can see it goes through loops and checks two big arrays each time pseudo element is found(not working correctly for :after, :before). I am talking that this part is memory inefficent. Also, the performence starts to feel when you check hundreds of thounsands or millions elements or at least tens of thousands.

Comment: +1 for providing working solution, but this solution does not work in my case, because i am working with many many elements. Script execution took 90 seconds to finish on typical small scale site(it crawls all site elements). Worst case scenario this should take about 1 second not more. :) Thank you.

Comment: ＋１  [`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) with its second parameter, specifically designed for this use-case.

Comment: This gives you the pseudo element not the pseudo class. They are very different things.